# Open source laf[look n feel] for java swing application

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

Which are Open source lafs[look n feel] for java swing application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a great answer on another question: [Java Look & Feel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3954646/155137)

**Edit**:
Don't forget the system look and feel:

```
try
{
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Substance](http://insubstantial.github.io/insubstantial/substance/) LAF from Kirill Grouchnikov is the best I know.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget

[Seaglass](http://code.google.com/p/seaglass/) : a LAF inspired by the OSX theme and, well, you knew it, seaglass (beautiful!)

[Nimbus](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/otherFeatures/nimbus_laf.html) : The standard Java L&F for Java 6