# Java cross platform Swing Look and Feel

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Look and feel in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954616/look-and-feel-in-java)

is there a third party pretty L&F for Java swing apps?
the default L&F are too plain.

Comment: Do you want native look and feel? [swt](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) does provide that.

Comment: @birryree: is swt totally different from swing?

Comment: yes, swt uses native look and feel, whereas swing emulates it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nimbus is a very nice look and feel.

Answer (score 0):

If you think default LAF (Nimbus, Metal and System Look And Feel) is not very good, you can search another LAF for Swing like on [javootoo look and feel](http://www.javootoo.com/plaf/easynth/index.html) :)