# JTable use Row Numbers?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row

I am creating a program to work like `Microsoft Excel`, in JAVA. My problem is how do I put the row numbers beside each row of the `JTable`? I have seen it working in other Java Programs - I just can not figure out how to include it in mine. Google gave me [this website](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/18/row-number-table/), and *apparently* it works. When I use it in my program this nothing happen. :/

I there a better way of adding row numbers in a `JTable`?

I have looked at the [Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) already.

I am sorry if this question has been asked before.

Comment: http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/18/row-number-table/

Comment: @Java you have to read discusions to the end...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There exists simple solution for that, and looks like as @camickr is more complex, (by Walter or Darryl from forums.sun.com)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TestTableRowTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                        if (info.getName().equals("Nimbus")) {
                            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    // UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                final JTable table = new JTable(10, 6);
                for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
                    table.setValueAt(i, i, 0);
                }
                final TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(table.getModel());
                table.setRowSorter(sorter);
                final AbstractTableModel model = new AbstractTableModel() {

                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    public int getColumnCount() {
                        return 1;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
                        return table.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getRowCount() {
                        return table.getRowCount();
                    }
                };
                JTable headerTable = new JTable(model);
                headerTable.setShowGrid(false);
                headerTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
                headerTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(30, 0));
                headerTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(30);
                headerTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new TableCellRenderer() {

                    @Override
                    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable x, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

                        boolean selected = table.getSelectionModel().isSelectedIndex(row);
                        Component component = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer().getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, false, false, -1, -2);
                        ((JLabel) component).setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                        if (selected) {
                            component.setFont(component.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
                        } else {
                            component.setFont(component.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN));
                        }
                        return component;
                    }
                });
                table.getRowSorter().addRowSorterListener(new RowSorterListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void sorterChanged(RowSorterEvent e) {
                        model.fireTableDataChanged();
                    }
                });
                table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                        model.fireTableRowsUpdated(0, model.getRowCount() - 1);
                    }
                });
                JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
                pane.setRowHeaderView(headerTable);
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().add(pane);
                frame.getContentPane().add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Toggle filter") {

                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                    private RowFilter<TableModel, Object> filter = new RowFilter<TableModel, Object>() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean include(javax.swing.RowFilter.Entry<? extends TableModel, ? extends Object> entry) {
                            return ((Number) entry.getValue(0)).intValue() % 2 == 0;
                            //return ((String) entry.getValue(0)).length()>0 ;
                            //return ((Date) entry.getValue(0)).getTime()< ;
                        }
                    };

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if (sorter.getRowFilter() != null) {
                            sorter.setRowFilter(null);
                        } else {
                            sorter.setRowFilter(filter);
                        }
                    }
                }), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private TestTableRowTable() {
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Good example; I had to add `frame.repaint()` after `frame.setVisible(true)` to get the header labels centered initially. Is there a better way?

Comment: Is there any way to use this in `Windows LF` or anything other than `Nimbus`?

Comment: then un-comment //`UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());` and disable all code `if (info.getName().equals("Nimbus")) { ...}`, but this question is really for reading this tutorial http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954616/look-and-feel-in-java