# Painting the slider icon of JSlider

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jslider

Would like to repaint the the marker or the thumb of the `JSlider` instead of the standard gray. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are three ways:

1. change [Java Look and Feel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954616/look-and-feel-in-java), `Preferred of Ways`
2. OverRide XxxSliderUI, but that would be Look and Feel sensitive, and not easy way
3. learning [The Synth Look and Feel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html)

### Example using Synth

[image: Synth slider]

#### SynthSliderTest.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.synth.*;

public class SynthSliderTest {

    private JFrame f = new JFrame();

    public SynthSliderTest() {
        try {
            SynthLookAndFeel laf = new SynthLookAndFeel();
            laf.load(SynthSliderTest.class.getResourceAsStream("yourPathTo/demo.xml"), SynthSliderTest.class);
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(makeUI());
        f.setSize(320, 240);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JComponent makeUI() {
        JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 100);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(slider);
        return p;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                SynthSliderTest synthSliderTest = new SynthSliderTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### `demo.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<synth>
    <style id="backingStyle">
        <opaque value="TRUE"/>
        <font name="Dialog" size="12"/>
        <state>
            <color value="WHITE" type="BACKGROUND"/>
            <color value="BLACK" type="FOREGROUND"/>
        </state>
    </style>
    <bind style="backingStyle" type="region" key=".*"/>

    <style id="SliderTrackStyle">
        <opaque value="TRUE"/>
        <state>
            <color type="BACKGROUND" value="ORANGE"/>
        </state>
    </style>
    <bind style="SliderTrackStyle" type="region" key="SliderTrack" />

    <style id="SliderThumbStyle">
        <opaque value="TRUE"/>
        <state>
            <color type="BACKGROUND" value="RED"/>
        </state>
        <state value="PRESSED">
            <color type="BACKGROUND" value="GREEN"/>
        </state>
    <!-- state value="MOUSE_OVER">
      <color type="BACKGROUND" value="BLUE"/>
    </state -->
    </style>
    <bind style="SliderThumbStyle" type="region" key="SliderThumb" />
</synth>
```

Answer (score 19):

Extending the [`BasicSliderUI`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicSliderUI.html) delegate is not without peril, but it *does* allow arbitrary control over the rendering, as suggested in the example below.

[image: BasicSliderUI subclass image]

```
slider.setUI(new MySliderUI(slider));
...
private static class MySliderUI extends BasicSliderUI {

    private static float[] fracs = {0.0f, 0.2f, 0.4f, 0.6f, 0.8f, 1.0f};
    private LinearGradientPaint p;

    public MySliderUI(JSlider slider) {
        super(slider);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintTrack(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        Rectangle t = trackRect;
        Point2D start = new Point2D.Float(t.x, t.y);
        Point2D end = new Point2D.Float(t.width, t.height);
        Color[] colors = {Color.magenta, Color.blue, Color.cyan,
            Color.green, Color.yellow, Color.red};
        p = new LinearGradientPaint(start, end, fracs, colors);
        g2d.setPaint(p);
        g2d.fillRect(t.x, t.y, t.width, t.height);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintThumb(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        Rectangle t = thumbRect;
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        int tw2 = t.width / 2;
        g2d.drawLine(t.x, t.y, t.x + t.width - 1, t.y);
        g2d.drawLine(t.x, t.y, t.x + tw2, t.y + t.height);
        g2d.drawLine(t.x + t.width - 1, t.y, t.x + tw2, t.y + t.height);
    }
}
```

Comment: I used this code but found I needed it to handle being disabled, so I added this code to lower the saturation of the color bar:          if (!this.slider.isEnabled())
 for (int i=0 ; i<colors.length ; i++) {
  float[] hsv = Color.RGBtoHSB(colors[i].getRed(),colors[i].getGreen(),colors[i].getBlue(),null);
  colors[i] = new Color(Color.HSBtoRGB(hsv[0], 0.25f, hsv[2]));
  }

Comment: Amazingly powerful and simply presented! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on TrashGod's very helpful answer, I added in a few lines of code to allow the bar to be filled up to the point in which you have moved it. The rest of the bar will be blank:

[image]

The code to do this is:

```
@Override
public void paintTrack(Graphics g) {

    // ... TrashGod's code ...

    // calculate how much of the progress bar to fill
    double percentage = (double)slider.getValue()/(double)slider.getMaximum();

    // fill the progress bar with a rectange of that size, (with curved corners of 4px diameter)
    g2d.fillRoundRect(t.x, t.y, (int)(t.width*percentage), t.height, 4, 4);

    // ...

}
```

And if you want a background color as well, paint a second rectange before you paint the first:

[image]

```
    // ... TrashGod's code ...

    // calculate how much of the progress bar to fill
    double percentage = (double)slider.getValue()/(double)slider.getMaximum();

    // PAINT THE BACKGROUND
    // create a gradient paint for the background
    p = new LinearGradientPaint(start, end, new float[] {0.4f,0.8f}, new Color[] {Color.gray.brighter(), Color.gray.brighter().brighter()});
    g2d.setPaint(p);
    g2d.fillRoundRect((int)(t.width*percentage), t.y, t.width - (int)(t.width*percentage), t.height, 4, 4);

    // PAINT THE FOREGROUND
    // create the gradient paint
    p = new LinearGradientPaint(start, end, fracs, colors);
    g2d.setPaint(p);

    // fill the progress bar with a rectange of that size, (with curved corners of 4px diameter)
    g2d.fillRoundRect(t.x, t.y, (int)(t.width*percentage), t.height, 4, 4);
```