# Set the size of a JSlider thumb

Tags: java, swing, jslider

How can the size of the thumb be configured for a `JSlider`?

With the defaults, and a range for the `JSlider` of 256, the thumb is only a few pixels wide, which makes it quite difficult to control with a mouse.

I am using the Windows 7 look and feel and the slider looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of slider]

Enabling `paintTicks` with a major and minor tick spacing of 0 gives a better (although not preferred) display:

[image: Screenshot of slider with paintTicks enabled]

The desired display is shown in the following image - taken from a native Windows 7 application:

[image: Screenshot of native slider]

Comment: How did you get it _that_ skinny?

Comment: It's a horizontal JSlider with min and max of 0 and 255 respectively, nothing special. When I reduce the range to 0 to 16, the thumb is the same size. When I change the minor or major tick spacing, the thumb is the same size. So I don't know why it's so skinny.

Comment: @Andrew Cecil, It would be cool if you included a screenshot. :D

Comment: @Andrew How much is `a few pixels`?  Which UI are you using?

Comment: Enabling the `paintTicks` property (but with no ticks) gives the following: [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/819/jslider2.png). That will probably do.

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992633/painting-the-slider-icon-of-jslider/6996263#6996263).

Comment: @trashgod, You should make that an answer. :D

Comment: @mre: Thank you; but, as Thomas notes, replacing the UI delegate is a last resort.

Comment: *"a better (although not preferred) display:"*  So what do you mean, wider still than the thumb in the 2nd screen-shot?  Also I'm thinking maybe I should delete my 'answer', since your post now includes & explains the images better.  Nice screenshots, BTW.  :-)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson - I've added explanation to the question of the desired look. Part of this is because enabling ticks (even with none displayed) adds space below the slider which makes a tight layout tricky.

Answer (score 3):

You could try customizing the `JSlider` Look and Feel as follows:

```
UIDefaults defaults = UIManager.getDefaults();
defaults.put("Slider.thumbHeight", HEIGHT_AS_INTEGER); // change height
defaults.put("Slider.thumbWidth", WIDTH_AS_INTEGER); // change width
```

Reference:

- [Customizing a JSlider Look and Feel](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CustomizingaJSliderLookandFeel.htm)

It's important to note that these changes will apply to all `JSlider` instances, which may make this approach undesirable.

Comment: At what point does this need to be done? Before setting look and feel? Before creating `JSlider` components? So far I have been unable to get this to have any effect.

Comment: @Andrew, Good question. I don't know yet.

Comment: Looks like these UIDefaults keys are only queried by Nimbus / Synth L&Fs (in Oracle Java at least)

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the SliderUI, which might have hard coded sizes. If not, using mre`s suggestion would be a way to go, if you want the same thumb size for all sliders.

Alternatively to setting the defaults for a UI that uses them, you could define a different UI for a special slider (e.g. `myslider.setUI(new MyCustonSliderUI())`), but be aware that that has its own drawbacks.