# JavaFX Canvas Rendering Performance

Tags: performance, canvas, javafx

I work on a JavaFX application and have to draw a lot (4000) of arc's.
I'm using the JavaFX Canvas method strokeArc of the graphic context.

The application performs very weak, but not the calls of the methods strokeArc, I think the delay occurs later, maybe at the rendering.
The results is, that the application does take a delay about 5 seconds to show the arc's on the gui.

Is there a faster way to draw the arc's in JavaFX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't. Canvas is the fastest.

You didn't provide a MCVE. I just tried a simple application. Works pretty fast, 4000 arcs drawn in 6ms. The application window shows up immediately. Here's the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.ArcType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ArcTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Group root = new Group();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(300, 250);

        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();

        drawShapes(gc);

    }

    private void drawShapes(GraphicsContext gc) {

        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        gc.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        gc.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        gc.setLineWidth(5);
        for( int i=0; i < 4000; i++) {
            gc.strokeArc(10, 160, 30, 30, 45, 240, ArcType.OPEN);
        }

        System.out.println( System.currentTimeMillis() - time);
    }
}
```

Unless you provide some code with more information (BlendMode, etc) it's hard to help you.

Comment: Maybe the built-in JavaFX Canvas Graphics Performace Optimizer realizes that drawing 4000 times an identical arc can be replaced by a single one here :-)

Comment: Thank you. I've tried your source code and it's fast for 4000 arcs.
The problem is, that I was wrong with the number of arcs. I draw not only 4000 arcs, I have to draw 70,000 arcs. And for this, your source code is also slow. I think there is no better solution?

Comment: Please try your test program with 70,000 arcs. You will see, the code is finished after 25 milliseconds, but the Java rendering has a very long delay.

Comment: @mipa yesterday: no, there's no optimizer like that

Comment: @jojo2100: you should phrase your question correctly then. 4000 and 70000 is a HUGE difference. The arcs are written into a GrowableDataBuffer and painted later. That's why you have that delay.

Comment: @Roland: I know, it is my fault. I have not realized this huge number of arcs before. So you mean, that the memory allocation of this buffer takes some time? 
Is there an possibility to get my application responsive, like with an task on a seperate thread?

Comment: @jojo2100: Not the memory allocation, the drawing. You are facing the same problem that I have with [the particles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613669/performance-for-particle-system). I doubt that you'll get it more responsive. I tried by splitting my app into several canvases, doing it parallel and then merging them. Didn't give any performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX Canvas implements *immediate mode graphics*. That's an engine where you tell it everything it will render every frame. Usually there's an object like GraphicsContext that represents a state machine that you modify before individual draw calls to get whatever style of drawing you want.

You may find that immediate mode graphics engines (like most platform's Canvas implementations) are utterly convenient but fairly slow at large scales.

When you want to draw a LOT of the same type of thing you need to start using the graphics card more directly. While the JavaFX Canvas does leverage graphics cards it doesn't optimize for what you're trying to do. Possibly the simplest approach to this are shaders. Shaders are essentially little rendering programs that OpenGL can run.

If you need to use JavaFX there are a few ways to use OpenGL with JavaFX. I'll offer a starting point here.
This is OpenGLFX, it will give you probably the simplest entry point for getting a shader running in your JavaFX application.

https://github.com/husker-dev/openglfx

I found that it wasn't especially elegant in the past but has streamlined a lot in the last year.

There are a lot of resources out there for learning OpenGL. For your purposes you should go through the first few tutorial here.

https://learnopengl.com/

Once you are ready to draw your arcs with OpenGL you probably will want to create a VAO (a common OpenGL arrayed data structure) with your arc data, upload that data to the gfx card, and render a *vertex shader* and *fragment shader*. OpenGLFX will take care of putting the result on the screen from the GFX card for you.

I imagine there are already plenty of algorithms and methodologies out there for rendering arcs simply or finely.

---

Of course if your arcs never need to change you could also just render it once with JavaFX canvas then use getSnapshot on the canvas to cache a picture of it and render that instead.