# Swing - Custom Buttons w/Synth

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, look-and-feel, synth

I am working on a project using Synth for the UI and want to implement some custom buttons. The buttons need to make use of style settings from a synth XML settings file - e.g. font colors which are different for different states (MOUSE_OVER, PRESSED, etc).

The problem I'm stuck on is that some of the buttons need to have extra sub-components - e.g. some need more than one label. I want the sub-components to pick up the same style settings as the standard button sub-components.

I feel like I ought to be able to just extend `JButton` and override/extend `paintComponent` to call the draw methods of some child components. I'm a bit unsure about a few aspects of that approach though: e.g. what parameters to pass to `paintComponent`; and how to ensure the sub-components get the correct Synth style settings (particularly wrt. the states).

An aside: I have tried extending `JPanel` but have run into some difficulties with that approach (see here: [JPanel states for Synth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768889/jpanel-states-for-synth)).

**EDIT:** So, I've discovered that it is possible to add sub-components to buttons and have them render correctly. It seems that even though `JButton.getLayout()` returns null, the button will use an `OverlayLayout` unless you call `JButton.setLayout()`. Calling `JButton.setLayout(null)` does prevent the OverlayLayout being used, so that's how I'm handling the layout.

I'm looking into a couple of different approaches to updating the styles for the child controls, will report back on those later.

Comment: Painting is handled by the component's UI delegate. See @mKorbel's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751311/creating-custom-button-in-java/5755124#5755124), cited in your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768889/jpanel-states-for-synth/7769341#7769341) on this topic.

Comment: I'm aware that the UI delegates handle the drawing, but since it's (as far as I can tell) basically impossible to extend the Synth UI delegates, I'm hoping there's more than one way to skin this cat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in case it's of use to anyone else here's the approach I took in the end:

```
class CustomButton extends JButton {
    CustomButton() {
        // ... normal button init

        // Enable absolute positioning of sub-components.
        setLayout(null);

        updateStyles();

        getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                updateStyles();
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateStyles() {
        // See below for implementation.
    }

    private int getSynthComponentState() {
        // This is basically a copy of SynthButtonUI.getComponentState(JComponent)
        int state = SynthConstants.ENABLED;
        if (!isEnabled()) {
            state = SynthConstants.DISABLED;
        }

        if (model.isPressed()) {
            if (model.isArmed()) {
                state = SynthConstants.PRESSED;
            } else {
                state = SynthConstants.MOUSE_OVER;
            }
        }
        if (model.isRollover()) {
            state |= SynthConstants.MOUSE_OVER;
        }
        if (model.isSelected()) {
            state |= SynthConstants.SELECTED;
        }
        if (isFocusOwner() && isFocusPainted()) {
            state |= SynthConstants.FOCUSED;
        }
        if (isDefaultButton()) {
            state |= SynthConstants.DEFAULT;
        }
        return state;
    }
}
```

I found 2 approaches to how to implement the updateStyles() method: (A) change the name of the component to use a different named style, or (B) copy the style settings from the button to the sub-components. Approach (A) is pretty straightforward, approach (B) works as follows:

```
private void updateStyles() {
    SynthStyle ss = SynthLookAndFeel.getStyle(this, Region.BUTTON);
    SynthContext sc = new SynthContext(this, Region.BUTTON, ss, getSynthComponentState());

    for (Component c : getComponents()) {
        c.setFont(ss.getFont(sc));
        c.setBackground(ss.getColor(sc, ColorType.BACKGROUND));
        c.setForeground(ss.getColor(sc, ColorType.FOREGROUND));
        // ... and so on if you have other style elements to be changed.
    }
}
```

Approach (A) is probably better if you're changing more than a couple of style settings with each different state, although it could get unwieldy if you have different styles for a lot of different states. If you're only changing a couple of style settings (e.g. in my case I only care about colours, at least for now) then approach (B) seems best.

There's also the approach suggested by trashgod of implementing a custom UI delegate (extending `BasicButtonUI`) but if you take that route I think you'll have to re-implement much of SynthButtonUI.