# Java JSlider with two set of labels

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jslider

Is it possible to display two set of labels with the same ticks on JSlider, one on top, one on bottom?

Comment: I can't see there any JLabel, maybe JTextField or JFormattedTextField

Comment: Why would you want this in the first place ? Each tick only represents one value, so why would you need to labels ? Will this not simply confuse a user. I do not remember seeing sliders with two different labels for the same tick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own `SliderUI`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6996263/230513), and override `paintTicks()`.

[image]

Alternatively, you may be trying to represent alternate units, such as Celsius v. Kelvin. You might want to consider one of these options:

- Add an adjacent toggle button to switch the displayed tick units.
- Add a second `JSlider` and let each one's `ChangeListener` set the other's model to the equivalent setting.