# How to use SynthLookAndFeel with xml file, where xml file path will load the file using getResourceAsStream method?

Tags: java, swing, jslider, synth

I am using

```
SynthLookAndFeel laf = new SynthLookAndFeel();
laf.load(MyJSlider.class.getResourceAsStream("/ui/demo.xml"), MyJSlider.class);      
//laf.load(new URL("file:///var/tmp/demo.xml"));
```

Where my demo.xml has following:

```
<style id="SliderTrackStyle">
    <opaque value="TRUE"/>
    <state>
      <imagePainter method="SliderTrackBackground" path="/var/tmp/JavaUnitTest/src/image/menu/bg.jpg" sourceInsets="0 0 0 0" />
    </state>
</style>
<bind style="SliderTrackStyle" type="region" key="SliderTrack" />
```

Causes error:

```
run-single:
Uncaught error fetching image:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getConnection(URLImageSource.java:115)
    at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getDecoder(URLImageSource.java:125)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:263)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:205)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:169)
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 9 seconds)
```

To avoid and to have less risks.

How can i use it like `path=Menu.class.getResourceAsStream("/image/menu/bg.jpg")`  where i wanted to avoid using the static path shown in example.

**Follow up:**

[image]

Comment: Please do have a look at [HOW TO ADD IMAGES TO YOUR PROJECT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230) and this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372350/1057230) of mine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a good example in [Advanced Synth](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-synth/).

You can see in the example that:

```
SynthLookAndFeel synth = new SynthLookAndFeel();
synth.load(SynthFrame.class.getResourceAsStream("demo.xml"), SynthFrame.class);
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(synth);
```

And `demo.xml` lives in  `demo.synth` package, the same of `SynthFrame` class, where this XML contains:

```
<imageIcon id="check_off" path="images/checkbox_off.png"/>
```

Where `checkbox_off.png` lives in `demo.synth.images` package.

Comment: Thank you. nice article. I have also modified my follow up section for better picture of this.

Answer (score 2):

1. please [to check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992633/painting-the-slider-icon-of-jslider), especially answer by `@trashgod` shows basic stuff but with great code workaround for BasicXxxUI
2. I'd be use `Nimbus Look and Feel` rather that prehistoric and plain `Synth`,
3. `Nimbus` has similair issues with GUI, aaaaand a few Bugs moreover,
4. `Nimbus` (based on plain `Synt`) could be easiest of ways and around us are a fews great hacks

Answer (score 0):

You can also add XML file by passing whole path of file

for e.g.

```
SynthLookAndFeel laf = new SynthLookAndFeel();
laf.load(new URL("file:///D:/Demo/src/example1.xml"));
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf);
```

It works for me. Try it for your application