# Is there a way to change the icon of a Jslider?

Tags: java, swing, icons, jslider

I am trying to do my own program and what the basis of what I want is to use some sort of slider to take characters to different buildings. I essentially have a one long vertical road with my bus (which is what the slider will be). I know the general icon for a JSlider is a small pentagon that can be dragged to different values. I was just wondering, is there a way to change that pentagon icon into something of my choice?

Comment: See [UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) for more info., but note those keys are PLAF dependent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to extend the `BasicSliderUI` and override `paintThumb()` to render the desired `Shape`. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6996263/230513) renders a triangle using `drawLine()`.

[image]