# Trying to implement a custom UI element into Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

It's supposed to take values between +100 and -100 (or something like that), and display this visually like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLaz6.jpg
My first idea were progress bars, but they seem to be unable to start anywhere but the start, and I need it to start in the middle.

Answer (score 4):

`JSlider` with custom background is more suitable than `JProgressBar`. See [How to Use Sliders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html) for some examples.

Comment: @user2247969 see [Painting the slider icon of JSlider](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6992633/1048330) for some examples on styling a slider.