# JSlider Thumb Icon style when pressed error on Custom Look and Feel

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jslider

I use a custom look and feel ([Darcula Look and Feel](https://github.com/bulenkov/Darcula) which is basically the Intellij IDEA Darcula theme).

I works great however this L&F does not implement a specific UI for JSlider and therefore the thumb icon bugs out when it's pressed or dragged.

Is there an easy way to only change this specific behaviour (since the rest of the PLAF really fits the needs of this project)?

I tried several UI settings that I thought might influence this behaviour (e.g. Slider.focus or Slider.foreground) but couldn't solve the issue.

Wrong:
[image: The slider button if selected, dragged or highlighted] Right:
[image: The correct button]

Comment: Ok to clarify: My question is, iś there an easy way to only change this specific behaviour since the rest of the PLAF really fits the needs of this project.

Comment: iś there an easy way to only change this specific behaviour  - I'm thing that not, or you have to delegate [own painting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992633/painting-the-slider-icon-of-jslider/6996263#6996263), get those value, then to put back correct painting