# while disabling the tabs in Jtabbedpane, there is no change in the look and feel of that tab

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I am using a JTabbedPane. In this i have to disable some tabs. i disable the tab using setEnabledAt(index,false) method. the tab was  actually disabled but i don't get look and feel [the color of the disabled tab text become light color]. how do i rectify it?

---

First i use default look and feel of java... now i change the look and feel to nimbus.. i found the color changes but the disabled tab  was not look like disabled checkbox or radio button or other component .

Answer (score 2):

I presume what you *really* want is to disable all the components on the disabled tab?

Swing doesn't work the way that setEnabled() of a parent component has any effect on the child components - you need to call setEnabled(false) on each and every one of them yourself (after all you *could* want some of them enabled, so Swing makes no assumptions and leaves it completely to you).

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't aware that there was supposed to be a change of the LookAndFeel,  but using the UIManager.put, you're able to alter the LookAndFeel of very particular parts, and I bet by manually changing the look/feel of a disabled tab, you may be able to get what you're after.

You can look at this page for a bit of help, and a link to all the look/feel options
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/color.html

Answer (score 1):

- most of method for `JTabbedPan`e is protected in the API, and not accesible from `Swing methods`
- have to look for `Custom XxxTabbedPaneUI`, override these methods, and could be accesible from outside
- correct way would be to implement [Custom Look & Feel only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954616/look-and-feel-in-java/3954646#3954646), part of them override `JTabbedPane` with `protected methods` too
- example for [Custom XxxTabbedPaneUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054466/how-can-i-change-the-shape-of-a-jtabbedpane-tab/7056093#7056093)
- you can to change `Foreground` for disabled tab quite easily, but works correctly only by using HTML syntax

code

```
tabbedPane.setTitleAt(2, "<html><font color="
    + (tabbedPane.isEnabledAt(int tab) ? "black" : "red") + ">"
    + tabbedPane.getTitleAt(int tab) + "</font></html>");
```

- I'd to suggest use custom `Look and Feel` or simple to change `Foreground` by using `HTML`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have an own Tab-Component?

Then you have to delegate the Enable-State to this Component.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;

public class Display extends JFrame {

    public Display() {
        super("Enable");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        this.setSize( new Dimension(300,300) );
        this.setLocationRelativeTo( null );

        JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane() {

            // delegating to tabComponent 
            @Override
            public void setEnabledAt( int index, boolean enabled ) {
                super.setEnabledAt( index, enabled );
                Component tabComponent = getTabComponentAt( index );
                if(tabComponent != null) {
                    getTabComponentAt( index ).setEnabled( enabled );
                }
            }
        };  

        JComponent component = new JLabel("Lorem");
        tabs.addTab( "", component );
        JLabel custom = new JLabel("disabled");
        tabs.setTabComponentAt( tabs.indexOfComponent( component ), custom );

        tabs.addTab( "enabled", new JLabel("Ipsum") );
        tabs.addTab( "disabled", new JLabel("Dolor") );
        tabs.addTab( "enabled", new JLabel("Sit") );
        tabs.addTab( "enabled", new JLabel("Amet") );
        tabs.setEnabledAt( 0, false );
        tabs.setEnabledAt( 2, false );
        tabs.setSelectedIndex( 1 );
        this.getContentPane().add( tabs );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Display().setVisible( true );
            }
        } );
    }

}
```