# how can i make check out progress bar in swing

Tags: java, swing

I want to create check out progress bar which to be run step-by-step like below image. how can i make this in swing. please give me some idea.

[image]

Comment: Overlapped button pairs with different colors and only one button in each pair is visible?

Comment: Why has the question received negative votes? The person is seeking ideas and could be a novice in swing. Our focus should be on encouraging individuals, rather than the opposite!

Answer (score 1):

1. this is about [customized JTabbedPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054466/how-can-i-change-the-shape-of-a-jtabbedpane-tab/7056093#7056093) (not easy and good job)

   - override `JTabbedPanes` methods `paint()` and with `paintBorder()`
   - use two prepared `Icons(ImageIcons)` into `JLabel` for every `tabs`, one for selected, 2nd for unselected
2. use two prepared `Icons(ImageIcons)` into `JButtons` for `JPanels` layed by `CardLayout`, one for selected, 2nd for unselected, notice - contents shoudn't be nice for resiziable contents, have to layout by GridBagLayout by using anchors
3. use `JLayeredPane` with `Icons(ImageIcons)` into `JButton` for `JPanels` layed by `CardLayout`, notice - there are max 6 members for `JLayeredPane`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of a checkout progress bar.

[image: Checkout]

When you left-click the "Next Step" button, the progress bar will increment one step.

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

I created a `JPanel` for each step of the progress bar.  I used a `FlowLayout` for the step `JPanels`.  I created a progress `JPanel` to hold all the step `JPanels`.  I used a `GridLayout` for the progress `JPanel`.

In the `JButton` `ActionListener`, I increment an `int` `stepIndex` which changes the background color of the appropriate step `JPanel`.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CheckoutProgressBarExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new CheckoutProgressBarExample());
    }

    private int stepIndex;

    private final Color highlightColor, normalColor;

    private JPanel[] stepPanels;

    public CheckoutProgressBarExample() {
        this.highlightColor = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
        this.normalColor = new Color(238, 238, 238);
        this.stepIndex = -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Checkout");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createProgressPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        JButton button = new JButton("Next Step");
        panel.add(button);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (stepIndex < 0) {
                    stepPanels[0].setBackground(highlightColor);
                    stepIndex++;
                } else {
                    stepPanels[stepIndex].setBackground(normalColor);
                    stepIndex = ++stepIndex % stepPanels.length;
                    stepPanels[stepIndex].setBackground(highlightColor);
                }
            }
        });

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createProgressPanel() {
        String[] text = { "Customer Info", "Shipping Info", "Payment Info",
                "Review Order" };

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, text.length));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        stepPanels = new JPanel[text.length];
        for (int index = 0; index < text.length; index++) {
            stepPanels[index] = createStepPanel(text[index]);
            panel.add(stepPanels[index]);
        }

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createStepPanel(String text) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
        panel.add(label);

        return panel;
    }

}
```