# Change colour of disabled JTabbedPane

Tags: java, jtabbedpane

I have a JTabbedPane with eight tabs. I have disabled one of the tabs using the code

```
 jtp.setEnabledAt(7, false);
```

My problem is that the tab label (just for the disabled tab) now has a dark grey background colour and I would like to change that. I tried the method setBackgroundAt but nothing happened. I checked the UIManagerDefaults (http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) but found nothing there about the colour of a disabled tabbed pane. How can I change this colour? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem. I used the CustomTabbedPaneUI class posted by mKorbel at this link: [How can I change the shape of a JTabbedPane tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054466/how-can-i-change-the-shape-of-a-jtabbedpane-tab/7056093#7056093) I then modified the paintTabBackground method so that the background colour of a disabled tabbed pane is white.