# JTabbedpane remove border from tab

Tags: java, swing, tabs

How can I remove border from tab ? Tabs' enable is set to false.

There is a picture for a better idea

[image]

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution: don't use a JTabbedPane. Instead perhaps you want to use a JList or JLabels, add a MouseListener and on mousePressed swap the view to the right using a CardLayout.

Comment: Thank you, this option did not come to my mind

Comment: @LOOK have to override the [BasicTabbedPaneUI](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7056093/714968), but carefully with:-)

Comment: This problem is sloved. Thanks :)