# firefox like tabs arrangement in Jtabbedpane

Tags: java, swing, tabs

Im writing a simple code editor in `JAVA` and iam using `Widows (System) look and feel` as in every code editor you can open multiple files in `tabs` but problem is if there big number of tabs they will arrange in multiple rows and i want to keep them in one row as `Firefox` do here is what happening with my editor

[image]

what i want to achieve is

[image]

kindly help me how to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and iam using Widows (System) look and feel as in every code editor
>   you can open multiple files in tabs but problem is if there big number
>   of tabs they will arrange in multiple rows and i want to keep them in
>   one row as Firefox do here is what happening with my editor

use this setting [JTabbedPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#JTabbedPane(int,%20int)) for quite similair output with FireFox  or Chrome on Win platforms

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(
     JTabbedPane.TOP, 
     JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
```

Comment: thank u so muchhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh i cant think it would be much simple :P but now how to customizr arrows?

Comment: but now how to customizr arrows? == JTabbedPane is one of awfull JComponents in Swing, no direct access to navigations buttons, have to override BasicsTabbedPaneUI,

Comment: search for Java + Swing + Ribbon (Ribbbon is originally in MsOffice)

Comment: thank u @mkorbel any snippet you can provide how to override BasicsTabbedPaneUI??

Comment: [BasicsTabbedPaneUI??](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7056093/714968), but look for Ribbon as easy, possible, correct way

Comment: ohh thank you bt i did not find much on ribbon with JAVA