# Missing 'top border' on JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, border, jtabbedpane, nimbus

[image]

I am adding tabs to the pane like so:

```
            JTextPane field = new JTextPane();
            field.setText("New test string");
            field.setEditable(false);         
            chatTabPane.addTab("Tab 1", null, new JScrollPane(field),
                    "Does nothing");
            for (int i = 0; i < chatTabPane.getTabCount(); i++) {
                 chatTabPane.setTabComponentAt(i,
                 new ButtonTabComponent(chatTabPane));
            }
```

However, unless i'm mistaken there should be a blueish bar along underneath the tabs? why is it they're floating way above the pane?

Comment: This question may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166875/nimbus-lf-missing-divider-at-jtabbedpane-set-to-scroll

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22217428/230513).