# Eclipse Plug-in Development - use Nashorn

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, nashorn

I'm developing an Eclipse Plug-in where I use Nashorn. When I run the same application as a standalone Java application, I face no errors. But when I run it as a plugin, I get this error -

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/nashorn/internal/runtime/options/Options
```

The stack trace further points to a location where I'm creating an Options object. I've already tried adding access restriction rules(just in case), but it doesn't help. I've also seen these two related links - [How to make jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.JSObject visible in plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655117/how-to-make-jdk-nashorn-api-scripting-jsobject-visible-in-plugin) , [Access restriction: The type 'Application' is not API (restriction on required library rt.jar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222811/access-restriction-the-type-application-is-not-api-restriction-on-required-l) , but the problem persists. I have double checked to ensure that the project is using Java 8.

Help?

Comment: Why do you use `Options` in the first place? Its authors have marked it 'internal', not to be used by clients, it may vanish at any time, it ties your application to the Oracke JDK and finally requires class loader hacks in OSGi.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann because I want to be able to do something like `options.set("anon.functions", true);options.set("parse.only", true);options.set("scripting", true);`

Comment: I can understand the desire/need to configure these options but still, you tie the application to the current version of the Oracle JDK, Future versions might simply break your application. However, you can let the OSGi system bundle export the restricted packages as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513083/depending-on-com-sun-javadoc-from-tools-jar-sun-jdk-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it working, but this seems more like a hack than an actual solution. I've copied `nashorn.jar` from `jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext` and included it in my build path.