# How to tell java's compiler to show the "is not API" warning for my code excerpts

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been trying to search how others tell Java compilator to show those warnings.

So far I noticed it (while making a plugin) that eclipse uses it and I know Java uses it for just about everything inside `sun.misc`.

I've been trying to find how can I do this for my own code but I can't find it. I was suspecting an annotation but, when reading the source code, I can't find any annotation that leads me to conclude it is an annotation that triggers it.

So, how to I show the "is not API" warning for the users of a library I do?

Here's an excerpt of code that makes the warning to pop up:

```
System.out.println(sun.misc.SharedSecrets.getJavaIOFileDescriptorAccess().get(new FileDescriptor()));
```

Sorry about it being incomplete. Did this help?

Comment: Include more details please What is this `is not API`? Please include real exceptions with real codes.

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222811/access-restriction-the-type-application-is-not-api-restriction-on-required-l ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then come back and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Jan did that change help? I don't really know what do you need in order to understand me.

Comment: @AlirezaMohamadi did that change help? I don't really know what do you need in order to understand me.