# Importing Apache Math Classes in Eclipse ( OSX )

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, apache, jar

I have downloaded the Apache Commons Math Package from their website, and extracted the `.jar` files.  Specifically, I took `commons-math3-3.6.1.jar`, and added it to my `/Libraries/Java/Extensions` directory ( on OSX ).

I then added this `.jar` file as an External Jar in my Eclipse Project's Build Path.

What I would like to do is use the `WeightedObservedPoints` class. But when I write the following line:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.fitting.WeightedObservedPoints;
```

I see the following error:

> `Access restriction: The type 'WeightedObservedPoints' is not API (restriction on required library '/Library/Java/Extensions/commons-math3-3.6.1.jar')`

Does anybody know how I might solve this problem?  It doesn't make sense that this class would not be in the public API.  Am I missing a `.jar` file to add?  There were several in the original package, but they all seemed like documentation and other optional features like testing.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222811/access-restriction-the-type-application-is-not-api-restriction-on-required-l

Comment: Thank you for that link!  The answer is inside it, although not set as the correct one >_<

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ivan, I did find the answer inside his link.  The steps to fix it for me were:

- Edit the JRE System Library on the Build Path option from the Project Properties.
- Change the "System Library" option to "Use Alternate JRE", but to leave it with the default choice ( which is the same as what was set for Execution Environment )

The error is gone.  Definitely don't know why this works though.

Comment: Glad to help ) Best wishes with your programming!