# How do I execute multiple JUnit test suites from a single class?

Tags: java, junit

I've tried to search on google, but I keep getting the same answer which is to use the following code:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({FirstTest.class,SecondTest.class,ThirdTest.class})
public class RunTestSuite {
}
```

However when I attempt to use this code in my program, I get multiple errors. All of them say the same thing: `Access restriction: The type is not API`.

Is there a way to fix this? Or another method altogether that I can use to execute multiple test suites?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? If so, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222811/access-restriction-the-type-application-is-not-api-restriction-on-required-l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative of this approach can be running all test cases of entire project. You can do this by simply right-clicking the project -> Run As JUnitTest.

If you want to ignore some of the test cases you can use `@ignore` with it. Hope this helps. I know this is not the actual answer, but just a work around.

Comment: This is a perfect solution. Much simpler than what I had in mind. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad to know that I could help you. You can mark answer correct.

Comment: Just did it now. I had to wait several minutes so I was unable to do it before.