# E(fx)clipse oxygen plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-oxygen

I'm using Eclipse oxygen the newest version (April 2018) & the newest version of Java (10.0.1). I've installed the e(fx)clipse plugin & still have the error: >Access Restriction: The ... is not API

How can I fix it?

I know the ways to set 'ignore' in preferences or add a rule in libraries & it won't satisfy me.
Thanks for all the helpers.

Comment: Can you give some examples for `...`? Is it a modular (with `module-info.java`) or a plain Java project? You get these errors in the Java editor, right?

Comment: Perhaps this SO post helps?... [Access restriction: The type 'Application' is not API...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222811/access-restriction-the-type-application-is-not-api-restriction-on-required-l/28331980)

Comment: Also, can you post the full error message?

Comment: I figured it out. Just changed in JRE System Library the environment to SE-10 instead of the SE-1.8 that was their.