# Bound mismatch and Discouraged access after moving from java6 to java8

Tags: java, java-8, java-6, bnd, access-rules

I have a very strange error after transfering a PDE project to bndtools and from java6 to java8. The structure is very complex but I'm sure it worked in the old version.

The error is in one of my classes where I try to initiate a new variable:

```
GenericStorageItem<SharedItem> result;
```

This results in the following error:

```
Bound mismatch: The type SharedItem is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Serializable> of the type GenericStorageItem<T>
```

The object SharedItem is defined like followed:

```
public abstract class SharedItem extends LSContent implements Storable
```

It extends LSContent which looks like this:

```
public abstract class LSContent implements PastContent
```

And finally PastContent contains the reference to Serializable:

```
public interface PastContent extends Serializable
```

The class that rejects to be bound is GenericStorageItem:

```
public class GenericStorageItem<T extends Serializable> implements StorageItem
```

In addition to this error I get the following warning on every use of the SharedItem

```
Discouraged access: The type 'SharedItem' is not API (restriction on required project 'the package where the class SharedItem comes from')
```

Because of this warning and because of the fact that this part of the code did work, I think that the issue has something to do with the access rules. I hade a look into the Project Properties and saw that the access rule Discouraged:** where at all external jars.

[image]

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222811/access-restriction-the-type-application-is-not-api-restriction-on-required-l) post, I tried to remove the rules but for some reason after applying it switches back again.

I hope someone of you has an idea on how to fix this issue.