# Encounter error when using Resource annotation

Tags: java, spring

I am missing something real simple.   I am trying to add a @Resource annotation to a setter method.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
.
.
@Resource
public void setCenter(Point center) {
    this.center = center;
}
```

I got the following error.  What is it looking for ?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access restriction: The type 'Application' is not API (restriction on required library rt.jar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222811/access-restriction-the-type-application-is-not-api-restriction-on-required-l)

Comment: See https://javahonk.com/access-restriction-the-type-resource-is-not-api/

Comment: Thank you Madhu.   I am still not sure what that error means but that solution did the trick.

Comment: For anyone who will encounter the same error,  I followed the link instructions and set the Access Rules value to "javax/annotation/**".