# Create a Java annotation for warnings - @NonOptimal

Tags: java, annotations, compiler-warnings

Is there something special to the `@Deprecated` annotation that I cannot reproduce?

I need to create an annotation similar to `@Deprecated` to produce warnings in Eclipse and also at build time. When I mark a method as `@Deprecated` I get nice warnings. For example, if I have an old method (that I may still keep for compatibility reasons):

```
@Deprecated
public List<Account> getClientAccounts(final int clientId) {
  // Implement search...
}
```

- Then, if I try to use it in Eclipse I can see it strikethrough, and a yellow icon in the left bar:

  [image]
- Also when building I can see the:

  > [WARNING] app1/src/test/java/com/app1/MyApp.java: app1/src/test/java/com/app1/MyApp.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

Now, depending on external factors I cannot control (e.g. absence of database indexes) some methods are not optimal, and I would like to clearly mark them as such... with my brand new `@NonOptimal` annotation. I need to add visibility to the problem. So far I have:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(METHOD)
// What else here?
public @interface NonOptimal {
}
```

How can I create this annotation?

Comment: in order to do something like this you need to create an annotation processor for the compiler, e.g. https://cloudogu.com/en/blog/Java-Annotation-Processors_1-Intro

Comment: @jtahlborn I'm trying to follow the instructions in your link but the compiler says those clases are not part of the API. I get: `Access restriction: The method 'JavaCompiler.CompilationTask.call()' is not API (restriction on required library '/apps/jdk-11+28/lib/jrt-fs.jar')`. Maybe this doesn't work in Java 11 anymore.

Comment: i believe that is an _eclipse_ restriction.  you may need to change some settings in eclipse to allow it to build your project: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222811/access-restriction-the-type-application-is-not-api-restriction-on-required-l/28331980

Comment: @jtahlborn Quite good option, actually. I implemented it for Java 11 and it works well during the build. About the other side (Eclipse warning, icons, etc) do you have any pointers?

Comment: For Eclipse, two options are to write an Eclipse plugin, or to run an external build (that is, call javac with your annotation processor).  The former can provide a nicer UI experience, but the latter is easier to implement and easier to apply to other IDEs.

Comment: @mernst I think an Eclipse plugin is kind of overkill. Plus I would need to ensure developers are using it. I was thinking more like using a standard IDE. I'll try running the external build to see how it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

@TheImpaler This is actually not a true answer for your problem, but some time ago I came across the [Google Annotations Library](https://code.google.com/archive/p/gag/) (a.k.a. gag) while using Zalando's Problem API.

This library provides a great number of custom annotations that, in some cases, can be used to instrument your actual code by using a ASM and a custom java agent.

Maybe it can give you some ideas regarding your actual issue.

The project is no longer maintained but there is a fork in [Github](https://github.com/stokito/gag).

Comment: Though your answer doesn't resolved the problem, I decided to give you the bounty, so it doesn't go to waste. These annotations, by the way, are quite funny (and some are even useful!).

Comment: Thank you very much!! I did not expect the bounty!! And you are right about the annotations; if possible, I usually use them in my projects. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 2):

I wish I could extend Deprecated, but no can do.

After reading about this quite a bit I ended up with an ugly workaround. It works, though I don't like it.

I decided to mark the *bad methods* with both the `@Deprecated` and `@NonOptimal` annotations. It's conceptually wrong (the methods are not actually deprecated) but it works well out of the box. No need to develop an overkill Eclipse plugin:

- The `@Deprecated` annnotation *bugs developers* all around the place (in Eclipse and when building), and that's a good thing.
- The `@NonOptimal` annotation *provides details* on why this is a bad method to use.

Ugly but works. As of now Eclipse does not provide any better option.

**Note**: to make things worse, the NonOptimal annotation does not work well in Maven when using toolchains: warnings go silent, disappear, nada... Therefore, AnnotationProcessors are kind of useless in the end.

Comment: You also need to configure Maven to build with your annotation processor and execute it.