# Associate JTabbedPane and JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, scrollbar, jtabbedpane

Hello I am trying to make use of a scroll bar depending on the number of tabs that are comprised in a JTabbedPane.

I have set the following code:

```
JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();
jtp.setTabPlacement(JTabbedPane.LEFT);
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(jtp);
```

My program works, however the tabs extensions doesn't match my expectations.

I have:

```
Tab1
Tab2
Tab3
```

After adding enough tabs so that their summed size get larger than my panel, they grow into a new line and the horizontal scrollbar appears:

```
Tab31 Tab1  
Tab32 Tab2
Tab33 Tab3
      ...
      Tab30
<--------horizontal ScrollBar??--------->
```

What I want is that tabs keep growing from top to bottom and the Vertical scroll bar appears:

```
Tab1
Tab2
Tab3
...
Tab30
Tab31
```

How can I do that?

HEre you will find an adapted piece of my program:

```
package eventListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;


public class TabbedPane extends JFrame {

private JTabbedPane jtp;

 public static void main(String [] args) {
     System.out.println("-----\nTest TabbedPane\n------\n");


     TabbedPane tp = new TabbedPane();
     tp.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     tp.setSize(300, 600);
     tp.setVisible(true);
 }

 public TabbedPane()  { //constructor for the tabbed frame you will be creating

        //This will create the title you see in the upper left of the window   
           setTitle("Tabbed Pane"); 

        //Here we are creating the object
           jtp = new JTabbedPane();
           jtp.setTabPlacement(JTabbedPane.LEFT);
           JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(jtp);
           //sp.add(jtp);

        //This creates the template on the windowed application that we will be using
           getContentPane().add(sp);

           JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();//This will create the first tab

           JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();//This will create the second tab


        //This creates a non-editable label, sets what the label will read
         //and adds the label to the first tab
               JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
               label1.setText("This is Tab 1");
               jp1.add(label1);

               //This adds the first and second tab to our tabbed pane object and names it
               jtp.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                   public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                       System.out.println("Tab: " + jtp.getSelectedIndex());
                   }
               });
               jtp.addTab("Tab1", jp1);
               jtp.addTab("Tab2", jp2);


            //This creates a new button called "Press" and adds it to the second tab
               JButton test = new JButton("Press");
               jp2.add(test);

            //This is an Action Listener which reacts to clicking on
             //the test button called "Press"
                ButtonHandler phandler = new ButtonHandler();
                test.addActionListener(phandler);




 }




//This is the internal class that defines what the above Action Listener
    //will do when the test button is pressed.
       class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
       {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
               {
                       //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I've been pressed", "What happened?", JOptionPane. INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                       for(int i=0; i<30; i++) {
                           jtp.addTab("Filter " + Integer.toString(i), new JPanel());
                       }
                   }
               }
}
```

Comment: depends on your details in SSCCE/MCVE/MCTRE form, note and LookAndFeel sensitive

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I furnished an adapted version of my code. If that's not enough tell me.

Comment: use SystemLookAndFeel, [more details about another unwanted issue is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481991/jtabbedpane-avoid-automatic-re-ordering-tabs-if-stacked-nimbus), otherwise you have to override TabbedPaneUI (better to search for any good custom LookAndFeel, by default most of them overrride all/most/part of problems with JTabbedPane)