# Making a Spotify-like look-and-feel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, look-and-feel

I'm trying to create a application where the taskbar and the JPanel(for example) has the same color, so that they look connected. Just like Spotify!

[image]

My way of doing this was to `frame.setUndecorated(true);` and then paint my own background and add Photoshopped jbuttons as exit and so on. It works, but! Its not very professional and not "right", I want to do this the proper way. I think they are using C++ at Spotify, but I'm more in to Java. Is that going to be a problem?

Comment: Do you want to do this for the Mac? Or cross-platform? It'll be hard to draw a custom border **and** make it blend into the operating system. Unless you have *lots* of resources, you'll have to decide on doing one *or* the other (and even with lots of resources, it will be tough).

Comment: Cross-platform i guess, but in first hand, Windows, is it hard to draw a custom border?

Comment: drawing a custom border is not that hard. Making it look *and feel* good is harder. Remember that you'll need to implement all the neat little features that a border has: resizing, moving, window menues, closing, minimizing, maximizing, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that [Substance](https://github.com/Insubstantial) or [JGoodies](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/looks/index.html) has similar themes; more about free Swing [Look & Feels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954616/look-and-feel-in-java),

For Substance you can't set `frame.setUndecorated(true);` because there it modifies the ToolBar, too.

EDIT:

Substance (but you have to download the code source) has implemented a preview for all known Java Swing Look & Feels in one `JFrame`.