# Custom design JScollPane Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, scrollbar, customization, scrollpane

I need to design this scrollbar for all my scrollpanes :

[image]

With Java Swing. I am using Netbeans IDE. What is the simplest solution ?

Thank you very much.

Regards

Comment: i did not get you. a scrollpane automatically inserts a scroll bar when size of element it contains is compromised.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can customize the look of a Swing component by **setting a custom UI**. In the case of a scroll pane's scroll bar, you do

```
scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUI(new MyScrollBarUI());
```

where `MyScrollBarUI` is derived from `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollBarUI`. To do this for all scroll bars (not only in `JScrollPane` instances), call

```
UIManager.put("ScrollBarUI", "my.package.MyScrollBarUI");
```

before you create any Swing components.

In `MyScrollBarUI`, you override the following methods:

```
public class MyScrollBarUI extends BasicScrollBarUI {

    @Override
    protected void paintTrack(Graphics g, JComponent c, Rectangle trackBounds) {
        // your code
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintThumb(Graphics g, JComponent c, Rectangle thumbBounds) {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Your scroll bar is graphically very simple, so it should not be too hard to implement.

Comment: Be sure to override `protected void paintTrack(Graphics g, JComponent c, Rectangle trackBounds)` and `paintThumb` (same method signature) in [BasicScrollBarUI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicScrollBarUI.html) or you might not see anything.

Comment: Would it be possible not to hardcode `extends BasicScrollBarUI` but to extend the scrollbar UI class that is currently used? Like `extends scrollBar.getUI().getClass()`?

Comment: No that is not possible with inheritance on the JVM

Answer (score 1):

1) override [JToolBar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html)

2) most of [Custom Look and Feel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954616/look-and-feel-in-java) overrode that

Comment: the relation of toolbar to scrollbar is that ... ;-) Plus (after all it's Monday morning): you override methods, classes are extended (or implemented)

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that if you plan to use the UIManager to override all scrollbars like this

```
UIManager.put("ScrollBarUI", "my.custom.SimpleScrollBarUI");
```

then your SimpleScrollBarUI class **must** have the createUI method, i.e:

```
public class SimpleScrollBarUI extends BasicScrollBarUI {

    public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c) {
        return new SimpleScrollBarUI();
    }

    //...

}
```