# Cannot change color of Titlebar and JMenuBar

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I try to modify either the color of the Windows title bar or the color of JMenuBar. I set every look and feel key to Color.GREEN via UIManager.put( "XXXXXXX", Color.GREEN), where XXXXX is just a placeholder. Most elements change but some not. See image for example.[image]

The red one is my problem (the others are stange too but okay).

GUI build with netbeans gui builder ( JFrame ->JMenuBar )

Maybe I should mention that:

1. Used LAF "Windows"
2. Used OS: Windows 10

**SOLUTION UPDATE - TEMPORARY**
Okay I got something working right now (cant test much will do later).
I have to create the JFrame befor changing to Windows LAF, this results in a frame like @bhavna garg and @Ganesh Patel then I change the LAF to windows and all other elements look like I wanted them. The colors are not right and it's not a feasable solution I think but I will check that later

Comment: 1) How to change titlebar color? [You can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482971/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-titlebar-in-jframe) as it's determined by the OS L&F. 2) For the `JMenuBar`, try the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648030/change-background-and-text-color-of-jmenubar-and-jmenu-objects-inside-it).

Comment: 3) `UIManager.put( "XXXXXXX", Color.GREEN)` there's no property called `"XXXXXXX"` in the [Swing UI Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951558/list-of-java-swing-ui-properties). 4) Your user will hate you if you leave that green background, (s)he'll have to use sunglasses to use your program... 5) If all the above tips don't help, consider posting a proper [mcve]

Comment: XXXXX is just a placeholder to descripe which function I used and as I mentioned I changed EVERY key (Mentioned here http://www.http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/11/all_ui_defaults_names_common_java_look_and_feels_windows_mac_os_x_and_linux#ArrowButton) that has a color Type to green (for testing my ui will not stay green forever.

Comment: @Frakcool I tried the answers (especally the marked) one but it didn't worked.

Comment: Okay, I think the only feasable solution is to create a synth look and feel and desing everything by myself. But I still think it's weird that the WIndows LAF ignores settings. But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer you  can use metal look and feel where I can change the color of title bar as well as change the color of menu bar and menu.

Here is code :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JRootPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.DefaultMetalTheme;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel;

public class MyLookAndFeel {
  JFrame frame;
  JMenuBar menubar;
  MetalLookAndFeel metal;
  JMenu menu;

  public MyLookAndFeel() {
    metal = new MetalLookAndFeel();
    metal.setCurrentTheme(new MetalTheme());
    try {
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel(metal);
    }
    catch(UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    frame = new JFrame("Hello");

    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME);

    menubar = new JMenuBar();
    menubar.setOpaque(true);
    menubar.setBackground(Color.green);

    menu = new JMenu("File");
    menubar.add(menu);
    frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(100,100);

  }
  public class MetalTheme extends DefaultMetalTheme {

    @Override
    public ColorUIResource getMenuBackground() {
      return new ColorUIResource(Color.GREEN);
    }
    public ColorUIResource getWindowTitleBackground() {
        return new ColorUIResource(java.awt.Color.green);
    }
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new MyLookAndFeel();
  }
}
```

You can see the Frame[image: Frame Image]

Comment: That works fine, but the look of some elements in windows mode is nicer, like the slider, they look nice in windows.

Comment: You don't like the few Element you can give your own UI by creating new custom UI class ` extends BasicComponent_NameUI` class for that component and call `setUI()`. Here is the Example :[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8209911/5855946)

Comment: Maybe thats a solution, I could create a new Implementation of JMenuBar like in the link you provided. But it's what's the reason I cannot change the color of Jmenu and JTabbedPane.

Answer (score 3):

[See for titlebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDy3F.png) [See This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7424.png)To set color of the titlebar use:

```
  frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(5);
```

5 is the constant that will give you a green color to menubar. You can use numbers between 1 to 8. Example: 8 will give orange color.

To set color of menubar use:

```
 menubar.setBackground(Color.RED);
 menubar.setOpaque(true);
```

Comment: frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(5); doesn't change anything maybe because I use Windows LAF and the second solution even not.

Comment: I have run the solution on windows LAF. It is definitely working for windows.  You can check the image i have added @dark_982

Comment: Which os you are running on? Windowsx Classic or just Windows LAF?

Comment: just Windows LAF @dark_982

Answer (score 2):

I switched to JavaFX. The original conzept didn't worked for me, but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late, but this may help others:

I searched the whole internet to find the way to change the entire theme of my swing-based app. then I found an article about doing so:

Somebody may say:

> Its not possible. The top level JFrame is controlled by the look & feel of the underlying OS.

If you want to access the title bar, first, you should have the access to the native java engine libraries. Fortunately, there is a way to it:

**First Step:** JNA provides Java programs easy access to native shared libraries without writing anything but Java code.
So you can use this repository to access to them: [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna).

```
Scroll down to readme and find the downloadable library.
```

Some elements may defer based on your platform you are using. So make sure you use `jna-platform-5.8.0.jar` to make your app compatible to any platforms.

**Second Step:** If you don't know how to use JNA libraries, then you could use this as an example: [example](https://github.com/kalbetredev/CustomDecoratedJFrame)

anyway, this could solve your problem about title bar color ;)

Main Article: [External Link](https://medium.com/swlh/customizing-the-title-bar-of-an-application-window-50a4ac3ed27e)

`Help me improve my writing in English by telling me my mistakes :D`