# Swing quaqua theme missing library

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application

In my swing application I have set `Quaqua` theme for look and feel.The theme works well.
But there is a warning:

`Warning: class ch.randelshofer.quaqua.osx.OSXApplication couldn't load library "quaqua64.dll". java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no quaqua64 in java.library.path
Warning: class ch.randelshofer.quaqua.osx.OSXApplication couldn't load library "quaqua.dll". java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no quaqua in java.library.path`

How can I solve this? I use Netbeans 7.0.1 IDE. How can I add `quaqua.dll` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this [Look and Feel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954616/look-and-feel-in-java) is built-in for Mac OX, then should be works

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```