# Exclude certain Jmenu's from Synth

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem, synth

I am using Synth L&F in a XML File, I set up everything so far, but no I have a nested JMenu, and I don't want the nested ones to take the style of the top JMenu's.

```
    JMenu accountMenu = new JMenu("Manage Account");
    JMenuItem editUsername = new JMenuItem("Change Username");
    JMenuItem editPassword = new JMenuItem("Change Password");
    accountMenu.add(editUsername);
    accountMenu.add(editPassword);
    fileMenu.add(accountMenu);
```

This was only taken from my code and edited to fit in, doesn't represent the actual code.

Then this is the Synth XML I snippet I am using.

```
<!-- ================================= -->
<!-- MENU -->
<!-- ================================= -->
<style id="MenuStyle">
    <insets top="2" bottom="2" right="10" left="7" />
    <state>
        <font name="Calibre" size="14" style="BOLD" />
        <color value="#cccccc" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND" />
    </state>

    <state value="DISABLED">
        <color value="WHITE" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND" />
    </state>

    <state value="SELECTED">
        <imagePainter method="MenuBackground" path="Bin/Images/headerbarActive.jpg"
            sourceInsets="0 0 0 0" />
        <color value="WHITE" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND" />
    </state>
</style>
<bind style="MenuStyle" type="region" key="Menu" />

<!-- ================================= -->
<!-- MENU ITEM-->
<!-- ================================= -->
<style id="MenuItemStyle">
    <insets top="3" bottom="3" right="20" left="5" />
    <state>
        <imagePainter method="MenuItemBackground" path="Bin/Images/menuItem.jpg"
            sourceInsets="0 0 0 0" />
        <font name="Calibre" size="14" style="PLAIN" />
        <color value="#cccccc" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND" />
    </state>
    <state value="MOUSE_OVER">
        <imagePainter method="MenuItemBackground" path="Bin/Images/menuItemActive.jpg"
            sourceInsets="0 0 0 0" />
        <color value="#000000" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND" />
    </state>
    <state value="DISABLED">
        <color value="WHITE" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND" />
    </state>
</style>
<bind style="MenuItemStyle" type="region" key="MenuItem" />
```

So now I am looking to target lets say only the AccountMenu JMenu and give it the same style as JMenuItems and not JMenus

To be more clear, please see picture:

[Menu Layout http://avengerpaintball.co.za/screen01.jpg](http://avengerpaintball.co.za/screen01.jpg)

File is a JMenu as well as Manage Account. So now the Account Menu takes the Style of File Menu, and that can't work, because they have different background Images.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

are you meaning ???

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel;

public class ButtonRollover extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ButtonRollover() {
        JMenuBar fileMenu = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(fileMenu);
        JMenu accountMenu = new JMenu("Manage Account");
        JMenuItem editUsername = new JMenuItem("Change Username");
        JMenuItem editPassword = new JMenuItem("Change Password");
        accountMenu.add(editUsername);
        accountMenu.add(editPassword);
        fileMenu.add(accountMenu);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SynthLookAndFeel laf = new SynthLookAndFeel();
            laf.load(ButtonRollover.class.getResourceAsStream("menusynt.xml"), ButtonRollover.class);
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ButtonRollover frame = new ButtonRollover();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and from file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<!-- ================================= -->
<!-- MENU menusynt.xml -->
<!-- ================================= -->
<style id="MenuStyle">
    <insets top="2" bottom="2" right="10" left="7" />
    <state>
        <font name="Calibre" size="14" style="BOLD" />
        <color value="#cccccc" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND" />
    </state>

    <state value="DISABLED">
        <color value="WHITE" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND" />
    </state>

    <state value="SELECTED">
        <!--<imagePainter method="MenuBackground" path="src/Paint/Images/failed.png"
            sourceInsets="0 0 0 0" />-->
        <color value="WHITE" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND" />
    </state>
</style>
<bind style="MenuStyle" type="region" key="Menu" />

<!-- ================================= -->
<!-- MENU ITEM-->
<!-- ================================= -->
<style id="MenuItemStyle">
    <insets top="3" bottom="3" right="20" left="5" />
    <state>
        <!-- <imagePainter method="MenuItemBackground" path="src/Paint/Images/passed.png"
            sourceInsets="0 0 0 0" />-->
        <font name="Calibre" size="14" style="PLAIN" />
        <color value="#cccccc" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND" />
    </state>
    <state value="MOUSE_OVER">
       <!--  <imagePainter method="MenuItemBackground" path="src/Paint/Images/failed.png"
            sourceInsets="0 0 0 0" />-->
        <color value="#000000" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND" />
    </state>
    <state value="DISABLED">
        <color value="WHITE" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND" />
    </state>
</style>
<bind style="MenuItemStyle" type="region" key="MenuItem" />

</root>
```

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly, I get that, but what now happens is that should you attach another JMenu to that JMenu. See My Image Included Now.

Comment: I see there some un-wanted whatever, hmmm question why use this L&F please to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954616/look-and-feel-in-java , there are tons alternatives with with great Bug History and real support, I tried Synth, but not satisfied with anything lots of works ...., maybe I lazy, sure I lazyness around, there is problem :-)

Comment: Thanks, but I do have my reasons for using synth, So do you maybe have any idea about what I am to do?

Comment: Thanks, I managed, I used the XML Property for a JPopupMenu (I Think)Thank in any case