# AWT and Swing component together, simultaneous display?

Tags: java, swing, awt, paint, simultaneous

I have to use both AWT and Swing component in my application. At displaying the AWT first appear on the screen then come the Swing component (with LAF style)

Is it possible that and make them appear simutaneously ? Like before paint, a kind of buffer ?

Thank you

Comment: *"I have to use both AWT and Swing component in my application"*  Why?  What AWT components are required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) since as of the [JDK 6 update 12 and JDK7 build 19 releases](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/), you can seamlessly mix [heavyweight (AWT) and lightweight (Swing) components](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/mixing_components/),But  I don't suggest mixing AWT with Swing,

2) its hard change [Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html) for AWT Components, I never saw good one, by default is there Look and Feel that came from Native OS, [Look and Feel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954616/look-and-feel-in-java) is about usage Swing JComponents

3) since is possible put JComponents with different Look and Feel, I'd suggest to create something similair

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;

public class ButtonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ButtonTest().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton opaqueButton1;
    private JButton opaqueButton2;
    private SoftJButton softButton1;
    private SoftJButton softButton2;

    public void createAndShowGUI() {

        opaqueButton1 = new JButton("Opaque Button");
        opaqueButton2 = new JButton("Opaque Button");
        softButton1 = new SoftJButton("Transparent Button");
        softButton2 = new SoftJButton("Transparent Button");
        opaqueButton1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        softButton1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(2, 2, 10, 10));
        frame.add(opaqueButton1);
        frame.add(softButton1);
        frame.add(opaqueButton2);
        frame.add(softButton2);
        frame.setSize(567, 350);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Timer alphaChanger = new Timer(30, new ActionListener() {

            private float incrementer = -.03f;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                float newAlpha = softButton1.getAlpha() + incrementer;
                if (newAlpha < 0) {
                    newAlpha = 0;
                    incrementer = -incrementer;
                } else if (newAlpha > 1f) {
                    newAlpha = 1f;
                    incrementer = -incrementer;
                }
                softButton1.setAlpha(newAlpha);
                softButton2.setAlpha(newAlpha);
            }
        });
        alphaChanger.start();
        Timer uiChanger = new Timer(3500, new ActionListener() {

            private LookAndFeelInfo[] laf = UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels();
            private int index = 1;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf[index].getClassName());
                    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
                } catch (Exception exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }
                index = (index + 1) % laf.length;
            }
        });
        uiChanger.start();
    }

    public static class SoftJButton extends JButton {

        private static final JButton lafDeterminer = new JButton();
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private boolean rectangularLAF;
        private float alpha = 1f;

        public SoftJButton() {
            this(null, null);
        }

        public SoftJButton(String text) {
            this(text, null);
        }

        public SoftJButton(String text, Icon icon) {
            super(text, icon);

            setOpaque(false);
            setFocusPainted(false);
        }

        public float getAlpha() {
            return alpha;
        }

        public void setAlpha(float alpha) {
            this.alpha = alpha;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g) {
            java.awt.Graphics2D g2 = (java.awt.Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, alpha));
            if (rectangularLAF && isBackgroundSet()) {
                Color c = getBackground();
                g2.setColor(c);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            }
            super.paintComponent(g2);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateUI() {
            super.updateUI();
            lafDeterminer.updateUI();
            rectangularLAF = lafDeterminer.isOpaque();
        }
    }
}
```