# Is there a way to support real \r carriage return without new line break in a JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, bufferedreader

I would like to know if it's possible to support '\r' (carriage return) without new line break in JTextArea or is this feature supported in any other similar implementations in Java?

Say, after several text appended to a text area, I want this to be appended.

"Please wait, a download is in progress"

After that a download progress status with progress meter character '#' gets appended.
e.g.:

```
#\r
##\r
###\r
####\r
#####\r
```

I would like to inform here that, I'm reading the progress from a buffer character after character. I don't want to replace the '\r' characters I'm reading from the buffer in any way.

So, what I would love to see if, the above progress, is displayed in a single line, without having a line break
Say,
     #########

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to marking progress in the `JTextArea` itself, consider decorating it with a [`JProgressBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) or a [variation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8886795/230513).

Addendum: `SwingWorker` is useful for managing lengthy background tasks while displaying interim progress. In this [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/randomdata), a worker iterates through a SQL `ResultSet` and updates a `JProgressBar`. Note that the GUI's `PropertyChangeListener` can update arbitrary components, and the progress bar can be [customized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8886795/230513).

Comment: Hi Trashgod, I think I didn't make myself very clear. The thing is several chars are being read from the buffer. I cannot put all the characters in a JProgressBar setProgress(). Only some part(characters) of the whole buffer have that #\r
##\r
###\r
####\r
#####\r
So if line break doensn't occur where there is '\r', it would mean the whole progress would look like progressing in the same line...
like #####, no line breaks in between. I'm ready to explain more if required.

Comment: I'm advocating a clear separation between the text component's content and any indication of progress. I don't see a way to both _change_ the content and _not change_ the content at the same time.

Comment: Hi Trashgod, by not able to change the buffer I mean, let's say I have the following content coming from the buffer, 'Download is in progress...**\r\n**Please wait...**\r\n**#\r ##\r ###\r ####\r #####\r\nDownload complete...'. So, how would I deal with this problem if I was to modify the characters coming my way. You got it ,right? **\r** can be anywhere other than my point of interest.

Comment: That's not how I'd do it. It looks like you want to simulate the appearance (or use the output) of a command line utility like `curl`. @MKorbel's [suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9931536/230513) seems reasonable.

Comment: Trashgod: Yes correct :) So do you have any other better solution to this problem? So if you get this type of problem what would you do?

Comment: @JtheRocker: I've elaborate above.

Comment: Trashgod: Thanks, will look and get back to you :)

Answer (score 2):

You have look at [public void read(Reader in, Object desc) throws IOException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: Thanks mKorbel, I have a look and revert back. :)

Comment: @JtheRocker: If you go this way, consider [`java.io.PushbackReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PushbackReader.html).

Comment: TrashGod & mKorbel: I would be grateful, if you guys could show me an example how this can be done using this technique :)