# How to change JProgressBar color?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jprogressbar

I Used `.setBackground` and `.setForeground` and they didn't work, the color is like Orange, can't change it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think that these values are right for you

```
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.background", Color.ORANGE);
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.foreground", Color.BLUE);
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionBackground", Color.RED);
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionForeground", Color.GREEN);
```

Comment: +1 for `UIManager`; see also this [alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8886795/230513).

Comment: +1 for this answer, but i wonder how to know the `value of the Key`, how will I know `UIManager.put(ProgressBar.whatElseCanIWriteHere, myValue)` , is there any Doc, which discusses this part, If there is one, please point me at it, I be highly Thankful :-)

Comment: @nIcE cOw there are a few www sites, but I use [UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/), because there are accesible all official L&F

Comment: @mKorbel : Wow :-) thankx for pointing out. That's impressive and quite informative. Exactly what I was looking for, Thankyou so much :-)

Comment: Shouldn't you change color only for THIS progress bar, not defaults for all progress bars in the application (like in Alex's post)?

Comment: @mKorbel  if i'm using netbean ,where should i put this code.i put them in constructor ,but still progress_bar is ugly default orange color

Comment: @madhawa priyashantha depends of NativeOS and used LookAndFeel, a.m. code lines are for metal look and feel

Comment: @mKorbel can i use this for Nimbus look and feel also?

Comment: @madhawa priyashantha yes but you have to override [Painter for JProgressBar](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A714968+%5Bjprogressbar%5D+nimbus)

Comment: @mKorbel finally i solved my case with your guidance

Comment: @madhawa priyashantha for excelent output to search for AbstractPainter, then is possible to create rounded corners (never used)

Comment: I'm still getting the same orange color!

Answer (score 20):

You should set the setStringPainted property to true:

```
progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
progressBar.setForeground(Color.blue);
progressBar.setString("10%");
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the best way to set an individual color.

Comment: But that would change the text color, not the progress color.

Comment: Just try, it changes the foreground of the progress bar

Comment: I guess it depends on the L&F you're using. That didn't work with Nimbus for instance.

Comment: Will this be the normal Java green progress bar that we are used to seeing in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
UIManager.put( "nimbusOrange", new Color( 38, 139, 210 ) );
```

It's works for me, only change the color, you can use Color.RED or similar