# Can't change JProgressBar color in Mac OS look and feel

Tags: java, swing, colors, look-and-feel, jprogressbar

I know this question has been answered before, but it's just not working for me. I followed the instructions from here: [How to change JProgressBar color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773978/how-to-change-jprogressbar-color)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ProgressBarTest extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        UIManager.put("ProgressBar.background", Color.orange);
        UIManager.put("ProgressBar.foreground", Color.black);
        UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionBackground", Color.red);
        UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionForeground", Color.green);
        JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(0,100);
        progressBar.setValue(50);
        f.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

All I am getting is the same old colors.

[image: AquaProgressBarUI]

I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.3 and Java 1.6. I tried the `CrossPlatformLookAndFeel` and it works with the new colors. However I want this in the default look and feel. How can I do this?

Comment: 1+ upvote for posting a valid [sscce](http://sscce.org) with formatted code on  your first post here.

Comment: But your code works fine for me. I see the requested background and foreground colors fine. I'm on a Windows 7 machine running Java 1.7.

Comment: I am on mac OS X 10.7.3 Java 1.6 and I'm getting what you see on the screenshot.
@HovercraftFullOfEels: It is my 2nd post. Thanks.

Comment: It could be a Look and Feel issue. Consider trying another Look and Feel to see what happens. We'll have to see what other Mac users experience with your code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It looked okay for me when I set a different look and feel. But I want it in the default look-and-feel for Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To override Look & Feel defaults, make the change *before* constructing the GUI on the [event  dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), as shown below.

On the `com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel`, the progress bar's UI delegate is an instance of `com.apple.laf.AquaProgressBarUI`. As you have found, it ignores many defaults in favor of the native component. If a novel color scheme is required, consider supplying your own UI delegate, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8886795/230513).

`AquaProgressBarUI`:

[image: AquaProgressBarUI]

`CustomProgressUI:`

[image: CustomProgressUI]

ProgressBar UI Defaults:

```
ProgressBar.background: com.apple.laf.AquaNativeResources$CColorPaintUIResource[r=238,g=238,b=238]
ProgressBar.border: javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource@47f08ed8
ProgressBar.cellLength: 1
ProgressBar.cellSpacing: 0
ProgressBar.cycleTime: 3000
ProgressBar.font: sun.swing.SwingLazyValue@6446d228
ProgressBar.foreground: javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=0,g=0,b=0]
ProgressBar.horizontalSize: javax.swing.plaf.DimensionUIResource[width=146,height=12]
ProgressBar.repaintInterval: 20
ProgressBar.selectionBackground: javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=255,g=255,b=255]
ProgressBar.selectionForeground: javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=0,g=0,b=0]
ProgressBar.verticalSize: javax.swing.plaf.DimensionUIResource[width=12,height=146]
ProgressBarUI: com.apple.laf.AquaProgressBarUI
```

SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ProgressBarTest extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        UIManager.put("ProgressBar.repaintInterval", 100);
        UIManager.put("ProgressBar.border",
            BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue, 2));
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5 , 5));
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.add(createBar());
                f.add(createBar());
                f.add(createBar());
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }

            private JProgressBar createBar() {
                JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
                progressBar.setValue(50);
                return progressBar;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: So, there is no **simple** way to have multiple JProgressbar's with _different colors_ but the _same style_ of the default AquaProgressBarUI, am I correct? (I won't be able to write my own UI delegate which will look as good as the default)


Thanks for the reply. I don't have enough reputation to up-vote or attach pictures directly.

Comment: +1 hmmmm [interesting look](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2007/tn2196.html)

Comment: can't you make the progressbars adopt different L&Fs by changing the overall L&F at time of creation of the progressbar (And afterwards set it back to a default L&F you stored before)? I Think i read this somewhere here...

Comment: Some UI delegates work fine like this; some not; you'll have not try it.