# Change shape of JProgressBar

Tags: java, swing, shapes, jprogressbar

I am new to Java but needs to know that if it is possible for a developer so that he/she can change the shape of the `JProgressBar`. I mean suppose in my case I want to change the shape so that it looks like a circle or something else?

Though I just want it to be changed from a bar shape to an arc shape or you can say i want to change the bar shape into any other shape. My progress bar may look like a curve other than a bar shape. I want to add a curve in it.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11148842/230513).

Comment: I want to use it as an arc and not in a linear shape manner or you can say can it be change in an oval shape too?

Comment: *"any hint"*  Users often detest the things that developers think are 'kewl' *"or any idea!"*  stick with the bar until you realize why that is.

Comment: @AndrewThompson raises an important caveat: consult the users. If only racing stripes will do, try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16182011/230513).

Comment: @all lols for your comments guys how useless you are !

Comment: @user2277645: For better answers, please edit your question to clarify your use-case.

Comment: Do you mean like this circular [dial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16182011/230513)?

Comment: yes offcourse @trashgod please give me a hint if you have any

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The appearance of a `JProgressBar` is controlled by the component's UI delegate, typically derived from `BasicProgressBarUI`. You can supply your own delegate, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8886795/230513), and override the desired paint method.

Addendum: For a semi-circular display, you may be able to leverage [`DialPlot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/dial/DialPlot.html) from the [`JFreeChart`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info) library. A complete example is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16163964/230513). You can use it directly or render the chart in your UI delegate.

[image]

Comment: I want to change the shape not the colors thanks for your help over and out @trash

Comment: You can use whatever color(s) you want; it won't automatically match the platform default, but you can use the UI [defaults](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11148842/230513) as a start.

Comment: You can also change the shape in the UI delegate, but then you can reuse less code from BasicProgressBarUI. Not an easy task. Check out http://javagraphics.blogspot.co.at/2008/05/angles-need-gui-widget-for-angles.html - here an "angle UI" is given to a JSlider.

Comment: @lbalazscs the link you mentioned has no such information sorry for asking from you

Comment: That link is just an example, it shows how one can use a completely different-looking UI delegate for a Swing component. It does not solve your problem directly.

Comment: See also this [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16333445/230513).