# Java Swing show progress in pie form

Tags: java, swing, graphic

I want to show a progress in pie format. Can anyone help?
I have the data to show, but how to show it in this format. Something like progress shown in Google Chrome when we download files.

[image]

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16182705/230513).

Comment: Nope i don't want to change the color i want to change the shape from rectangle to circle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the links provided by @trashgod, here is one way you can achieve a "Pie" effect. This only handles the indeterminate progress bar, but it would be very easy to add the "determinate" behaviour.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicProgressBarUI;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884297 */
public class ProgressBarUITest extends JPanel {

    public ProgressBarUITest() {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        JProgressBar jpb = new JProgressBar();
        jpb.setUI(new MyProgressUI());
        jpb.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
        jpb.setIndeterminate(true);
        this.add(jpb);
    }

    private static class MyProgressUI extends BasicProgressBarUI {

        private static final int ARC_EXTENT = 25;

        @Override
        protected void installDefaults() {
            super.installDefaults();
            progressBar.setBorder(null);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintIndeterminate(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
            int angle = (int) (90 - 360.0 * getAnimationIndex() / getFrameCount());
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g.setColor(progressBar.getForeground());
            int size = Math.min(c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
            g2d.fillArc((c.getWidth() - size) / 2, (c.getHeight() - size) / 2, size, size, angle - ARC_EXTENT, ARC_EXTENT);
        }

        @Override
        protected Rectangle getBox(Rectangle r) {
            if (r != null) {
                r.setBounds(progressBar.getBounds());
                return r;
            }
            return progressBar.getBounds();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize(JComponent c) {
            return new Dimension(100, 100);
        }
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("ProgressBarUITest");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ProgressBarUITest().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: as we set the value and do intermidiate false this stops working :(

Comment: @Skyscraper This is exactly what my first sentence says. Please take the time to fully read answers before. From the code above, it is trivial to do the determinate one!

Comment: +1 for `fillArc()`, lighter weight that my [suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16182793/230513). :-)