# JProgressBar background colour

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

I am trying to set the foreground colour of progress bars to green, and the background colour to yellow, I am doing the following

```
  JProgressBar pb = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
  pb.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
  pb.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
  pb.setForeground(Color.GREEN.darker());
  pb.setOpaque(true);
  pb.setStringPainted(true);
  pb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(pb.getPreferredSize().width, 16));
```

I expected the bar to be yellow, instead the colour behind the bar is yellow. See below (I have tried the UIManager approach as well)

[image]

EDIT: It looks like it's the Windows L&F that's causing the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773978/how-to-change-jprogressbar-color

Comment: As I said I have tried the UIManager approach mentioned in that post

Comment: Then I recommend posting a full example that shows exactly what you've tried so that we can copy and paste it and run it ourselves. AKA an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Two approaches are suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16625494/230513); if the former fails, try the latter.

Comment: @trashgod thanks, it looks like it's the windows L&F that is causing this so I guess using ProgressBarUI is my only option?

Comment: I like [tag:jfreechart], either stand-alone or in a custom delegate.

Comment: The ProgressBarUI approach worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity would it improve it if you `setopaque = false;`

Comment: Unfortunately not, the yellow outline disappears in that case. I have a feeling it's something specific to using JIDE components, hmmmm

Answer (score 0):

```
progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
progressBar.setForeground(Color.GREEN.darker());
progressBar.background(Color.YELLOW);
progressBar.setString("50%");
```

Try this..