# How to change a JProgressBar Text Color

Tags: java

```
     UIManager.put("jb.selectionForeground", new ColorUIResource(Color.BLACK));
     UIManager.put("jb.selectionBackground", new ColorUIResource(Color.BLACK));
```

I tried this method, but its not working.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773978/how-to-change-jprogressbar-color

Answer (score 0):

You can Easily Set The JProgressBar Text Color Using  :-

```
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionBackground", Color.RED);//Red
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionForeground", Color.GREEN);//Green 
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.background", Color.ORANGE);//Gives Orange
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.foreground", Color.BLUE);//Gives Blue
```

For More Details Go : [How to change JProgressBar color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773978/how-to-change-jprogressbar-color)

Happy to Help !