# Java - change colour of JProgressBar on Mac (without UIManager)

Tags: java, swing, colors, uicolor, jprogressbar

I want to change the color of the JProgressbar but it don't work. I can change the Color around the JProgressBar with setBackground, but not the Color of the Bar itself. setForeground is however not working for me in this case.
I don't use UiManager or any other kind like that. I just use swing and awt.
The debugger said that the Foregroundcolor has changed but it visually doesn't. Is it possible that the Mac progress bar can't change its foreground visually?

```
//create Progressbar
progBarHeroLife = new JProgressBar(0, Hero.Life.max);
progBarHeroLife.setBounds(25, 676, 200, 50);
progBarHeroLife.setStringPainted(true);
progBarHeroLife.setOpaque(true);
progBarHeroLife.setForeground(Color.orange);
progBarHeroLife.setString(String.valueOf(Hero.Life.actual) + "/" + String.valueOf(Hero.Life.max));
progBarHeroLife.setValue(Hero.Life.actual);

controlePanel.add(progBarHeroLife);
myFrame.add(gamePanel);
```

[Thats how it look like actually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDzsO.png)

And here is the full source code for the window

```
package com.company.Game;


import com.company.Characters.Hero;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Window implements ActionListener
{
    public static int scale = 20;

    public static JFrame meinFrame;
    public static int heightMeinFrame = 800;
    public static int heightGamePanel = 500;
    public static int heightControlePanel = 300;
    public static int heightLabelBackground = heightGamePanel;
    public static int widthMeinFrame = 1000;
    public static int widthGamePanel = 1000;
    public static int widthControlePanel = 1000;
    public static int widthLabelBackground = widthGamePanel;

    public static int offsetPlayerY = -(5*scale);

    public static JPanel gamePanel;
    public static JPanel controlePanel;
    public static JLabel labelBackground;
    static ImageIcon backgroundIcon = new ImageIcon("/Users/MJulich/IdeaProjects/Spiel mit Gui/src/Imports/Background.png");
    static JProgressBar progBarHeroLife;
    static JProgressBar progBarHeroMana;
    static JButton myJBtn1;
    static JButton myJBtn2;
    static JButton myJBtn3;
    static JButton myJBtn4;
    static JButton myJBtn5;
    static JButton myJBtn6;
    static JButton myJBtn7;
    static JButton myJBtn8;

    public Window()
    {
        //create Frame
        meinFrame = new JFrame("Mein JFrame Beispiel");
        meinFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        /* Wir setzen die Breite unseres Fensters auf 1000 Pixel
        und die Höhe unseres Fensters auf 800 Pixel */
        meinFrame.setSize(widthMeinFrame, heightMeinFrame);
        meinFrame.setResizable(false);

            //create gamePanel
            gamePanel = new JPanel();
            gamePanel.setLayout(null);
            gamePanel.setBounds(0, 0, widthGamePanel, heightGamePanel);

                //create Background
                backgroundIcon.setImage(backgroundIcon.getImage().getScaledInstance(widthLabelBackground, heightLabelBackground, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
                labelBackground = new JLabel(backgroundIcon);
                labelBackground.setOpaque(true);
                labelBackground.setBounds(0,0,widthLabelBackground,heightLabelBackground);
                PaintObjects.paintNew();
                gamePanel.add(labelBackground);


            //create controlePanel
            controlePanel = new JPanel();
            controlePanel.setLayout(null);
            controlePanel.setBounds(0, heightGamePanel+1, widthControlePanel, heightControlePanel);
            controlePanel.setBackground(new Color(200,200,255));

                //create Buttons
                myJBtn1 = new JButton("1");
                myJBtn1.setBounds(25, 526, 200, 50);
                myJBtn2 = new JButton("2");
                myJBtn2.setBounds(275, 526, 200, 50);
                myJBtn3 = new JButton("3");
                myJBtn3.setBounds(525, 526, 200, 50);
                myJBtn4 = new JButton("4");
                myJBtn4.setBounds(775, 526, 200, 50);
                myJBtn5 = new JButton("5");
                myJBtn5.setBounds(25, 601, 200, 50);
                myJBtn6 = new JButton("6");
                myJBtn6.setBounds(275, 601, 200, 50);
                myJBtn7 = new JButton("7");
                myJBtn7.setBounds(525, 601, 200, 50);
                myJBtn8 = new JButton("8");
                myJBtn8.setBounds(775, 601, 200, 50);

                myJBtn1.addActionListener(this);
                myJBtn2.addActionListener(this);
                myJBtn3.addActionListener(this);
                myJBtn4.addActionListener(this);
                myJBtn5.addActionListener(this);
                myJBtn6.addActionListener(this);
                myJBtn7.addActionListener(this);
                myJBtn8.addActionListener(this);

                //create Progressbar
                progBarHeroLife = new JProgressBar(0, Hero.Life.max);
                progBarHeroLife.setBounds(25, 676, 200, 50);
                progBarHeroLife.setStringPainted(true);
                progBarHeroLife.setOpaque(true);
                /**einfärben funktioniert noch nicht*/
                progBarHeroLife.setForeground(Color.yellow);
                progBarHeroLife.setString(String.valueOf(Hero.Life.actual) + "/" + String.valueOf(Hero.Life.max));
                progBarHeroLife.setValue(Hero.Life.actual);

                //add Buttons and Progressbar to controlePanel
                controlePanel.add(myJBtn1);
                controlePanel.add(myJBtn2);
                controlePanel.add(myJBtn3);
                controlePanel.add(myJBtn4);
                controlePanel.add(myJBtn5);
                controlePanel.add(myJBtn6);
                controlePanel.add(myJBtn7);
                controlePanel.add(myJBtn8);
                controlePanel.add(progBarHeroLife);

            //add Panels to Frame
            meinFrame.add(gamePanel);
            meinFrame.add(controlePanel);

        //show Frame
        meinFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)
    {
        // Die Quelle wird mit getSource() abgefragt und mit den
        // Buttons abgeglichen. Wenn die Quelle des ActionEvents einer
        // der Buttons ist, wird der Text des JLabels entsprechend geändert
        if(ae.getSource() == myJBtn1){
            ButtonListener.buttonPressed(1);
        }
        else if(ae.getSource() == myJBtn2){
            ButtonListener.buttonPressed(2);
        }
        else if(ae.getSource() == myJBtn3){
            ButtonListener.buttonPressed(3);
        }
        else if(ae.getSource() == myJBtn4){
            ButtonListener.buttonPressed(4);
        }
        else if(ae.getSource() == myJBtn5){
            ButtonListener.buttonPressed(5);
        }
        else if(ae.getSource() == myJBtn6){
            ButtonListener.buttonPressed(6);
        }
        else if(ae.getSource() == myJBtn7){
            ButtonListener.buttonPressed(7);
        }
        else if(ae.getSource() == myJBtn8){
            ButtonListener.buttonPressed(8);
        }
    }
}
```

(I know that i don't need to have everything public.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change JProgressBar color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773978/how-to-change-jprogressbar-color)

Comment: No, i said i don't use UIManager.

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem. Please try to create a [SSCCE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions). If I create a `JProgressBar` like you did in a simple `JFrame` it is orange as expected.

Comment: *"I don't use UiManager or toothbrush or what its called. I just use swing and awt."* You bang rocks together to make fire? [`UIManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html) is **part of** Swing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has refused to do it using the API designed for the task.

Comment: Sorry guys I'm new with Java, I don't know anything about UIManager.

Comment: The curios thing is that setBackground works, but setForeground not.

Answer (score 0):

You should be set setStringPainted() as true. This should work.

```
progBarHeroLife.setStringPainted(true);
progBarHeroLife.setForeground(Color.red);
progBarHeroLife.setString("10%");
```

OR  You can use UIManager as follows (I know you have mentioned without UIManager). But that is the easy way.

```
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.background", Color.BLACK); //colour of the background
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.foreground", Color.RED);  //colour of progress bar
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionBackground",Color.YELLOW);  //colour of percentage counter on black background
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionForeground",Color.BLUE);  //colour of precentage counter on red background
```

Refer:https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/315100/how-to-change-color-progressbar

https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/315100/how-to-change-color-progressbar

Comment: As you can see in my code `setStringPainted` is already true.

Comment: I added`UIManager.put("progBarHeroLife.background", Color.BLACK); //colour of the background
        UIManager.put("progBarHeroLife.foreground", Color.RED);  //colour of progress bar
        UIManager.put("progBarHeroLife.selectionBackground",Color.YELLOW);  //colour of percentage counter on black background
        UIManager.put("progBarHeroLife.selectionForeground",Color.BLUE);`

Comment: I checked this example: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Progressbardemosetselectionbackgroundselectionforegroundandforeground.htm   with above UIManager code. It is working perfectly. Pls first check this as separate class.

Comment: Can you define your class as public class Window extends JFrame implements ActionListener

Comment: it's blue too. I turned the color you inserted (`UIManager.put("ProgressBar.foreground", new Color(8, 32, 128));`) from blue to purple. Still blue.

Comment: I think its a problem with MacOs and how its showing java progress bars

Comment: Check with this: UIManager.put("ProgressBarUI","javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalProgressBarUI" ); Pls remove previous code

Comment: UIDefaults.getUI() failed: no ComponentUI class for: javax.swing.JProgressBar[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=0,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,orientation=HORIZONTAL,paintBorder=false,paintString=false,progressString=,indeterminateString=false]
java.lang.Error