# JProgressbar with 2 or more different colors at one instance

Tags: java, swing, colors, foreground, jprogressbar

I wanted to create a `jprogressbar` that has a specific color on a specific range (eg. 50% green, 50% red). Is there a way to do that? What i currently have is a progressbar that changes the color of the whole bar. By the way i am not using any `look and feels` for this one. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Extend `BasicProgressBarUI` and override the the desired `paint()` delegate, as shown in this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8886795/230513) that overrides `paintIndeterminate()`.

[image]