# text alignment in JProgressBar on OSX

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar, text-alignment

I have a JPanel with a number of JProgressBar components on it. It works fine with the default behavior of centering the paintString. I would like to left-justify all the paint strings. I don't see any way to apply formatting to the text string. I suppose I could place the text myself with a JLabel, but I'd rather do the formatting in the JProgressBar itself. How is this accomplished?

Comment: Nope, there is no feature to enable this, you'd have to implement your own look and feel

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8886795/230513).