# can not set quaqua look and feel in java

Tags: java, windows, macos, swing, look-and-feel

Im facing the problem in setting the quaqua look and feel and getting this error on windows seven:

```
Warning: ch.randelshofer.quaqua.util.Preferences failed to load Mac OS X global system preferences
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\A.Rahman\Library\Preferences\.GlobalPreferences.plist (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

this is the code fro setting look and feel :

```
try {    

        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("ch.randelshofer.quaqua.QuaquaLookAndFeel");
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

it seems your lookAndFel it is supported by mac only, because it is card-coded inside of him to load a .plist ( specific for mac) even is he on windows.

You can write the windows implementation of lookandfeel
You can write to developers to write.
Doublecheck what version have you installed on windows.

Comment: @Arshad the Lover you can to [set Quaqua LookAndFeel on Win OS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9260628/714968), but caused many of graphical defects, those problems aren't side effects, one big mess