# high level Java swing gui frameworks

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, look-and-feel

what are some of the solid high level java swing gui frameworks out there that can be used to make visually appealing java GUIs without too much efforts?
Similarly what are some of the solid Look&Feel commercial grade packages out there that we can just use to plug into existing java swing guis to make it visually appealing and professional looking?

Comment: What is wrong with simply using Swing?

Comment: I found http://www.jgoodies.com/ really awesome ones though. I'd rather highly recommend them they have samples here http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/index.html you can test them at once.

Comment: @m92: what's wrong with simply using javascript as opposed to jquery and other high level javascript frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Similarly what are some of the solid Look&Feel commercial grade packages out there that we can just use to plug into existing java swing guis to make it visually appealing and professional looking?

Synthetica http://www.jyloo.com/

Answer (score 1):

> what are some of the solid high level java swing gui frameworks out there that can be used to make visually appealing java GUIs without too much efforts?

- [Google Window Builder](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/) **+1**
- [NetBeans Swing GUI Builder](http://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html)

> Similarly what are some of the solid Look&Feel commercial grade packages out there that we can just use to plug into existing java swing guis to make it visually appealing and professional looking?

- [Nimbus Look & Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html)
- [Java Look and Feel (L&F)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954616/look-and-feel-in-java/3954646#3954646)

Answer (score 1):

1) `solid high level java swing gui frameworks`

- wrote all Java code by your hands, Swing is very old GUI framework and everything is there possible (AFAIK), be free and never will be restricted by implemented methods in the API for XxxFramework,
- maybe SwingX for hightlever workaround, but in other hands required very good knowledge from Swing and very good from Java

2) `solid Look&Feel`

list of [Custom Look and Feels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3954646/714968)