# Eliminating dropdown menu from JMenu set by setJMenuBar

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jmenubar

If you create a JMenuBar for a JFrame in the [usual way](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html), this JMenuBar has an application menu with menu items *Move*, *Size*, *Minimize*, and so on as pictured below.

[image: image of JMenuBar application menu]

You get to this menu by clicking on the little Java coffee cup in the upper left-hand corner.

Is there a way to create a JMenuBar without access to this application menu?

Comment: *"..as pictured below."*  If you're going to post a screen-shot, at least get your facts right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `Top-Level Containers` came from Native OS, where all `Containers` have got the same decorations and `ToolBar` with `Buttons`, with identical behaviour,
- AFAIK not possible as I know, without implementing [Custom Look and Feel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3954646/714968), e.g some `Substance` themes have got own customized `ToolBar`

or

- you can create un_decorated `JFrame / JDialog` and then to create own `ToolBar` and/or `Buttons` for iconify, maximize and close