# Not Editable JComboBox Border

Tags: java, swing, border, jcombobox

I am using Metal L&F. I want to make a **JComboBox**, that has only 1 pixel border. This not a problem, as long as the cb is **editable**. This corresponds to the first cb in the picture named "Editable".

```
cb.setEditable(true);
((JTextComponent) (cb.getEditor().getEditorComponent())).setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 0, COLOR));
```

But when I do **cb.setEditable(false)**, an additional border occurs inside the box (changed to red in the picture "Dropdown", you see the original color in the picture named "Fixed"). Although I tried to set the border and I also tried to use my own CellRenderer, the border still gets painted. It seems to me, that the unwanted border does not come from the CellRenderer. When I try to manipulate the border from the cb itself (see comment //), it only adds/removes an additional outer border. The editorComponent also seems not to be responsible to me.

```
cb.setRenderer(new CbCellRenderer());
//cb.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, COLOR));
//cb.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());

class CbCellRenderer implements ListCellRenderer {

    protected DefaultListCellRenderer defaultRenderer = new DefaultListCellRenderer();

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        JLabel renderer = (JLabel) defaultRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        renderer.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        return renderer;
    }        
}
```

I also tried out some UI variables like the ones below without taking affect on this border.

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
UIManager.put("ComboBox.selectionForeground", Color.green);
UIManager.put("ComboBox.disabledBackground", Color.green);
...
```

[image]

Image: http://upload.mtmayr.com/dropdown_frame.png <sup>(link broken)</sup>

Complete code for testing:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup;

public class ComboTest {

    private Vector<String> listSomeString = new Vector<String>();
    private JComboBox editableComboBox = new JComboBox(listSomeString);
    private JComboBox nonEditableComboBox = new JComboBox(listSomeString);
    private JFrame frame;
    public final static Color COLOR_BORDER = new Color(122, 138, 153);

    public ComboTest() {
        listSomeString.add("row 1");
        listSomeString.add("row 2");
        listSomeString.add("row 3");
        listSomeString.add("row 4");

        editableComboBox.setEditable(true);
        editableComboBox.setBackground(Color.white);
        Object child = editableComboBox.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleChild(0);
        BasicComboPopup popup = (BasicComboPopup) child;
        JList list = popup.getList();
        list.setBackground(Color.white);
        list.setSelectionBackground(Color.red);
        JTextField tf = ((JTextField) editableComboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent());
        tf.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 0, COLOR_BORDER));

        nonEditableComboBox.setEditable(false);
        nonEditableComboBox.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        nonEditableComboBox.setBackground(Color.white);
        Object childNonEditable = nonEditableComboBox.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleChild(0);
        BasicComboPopup popupNonEditable = (BasicComboPopup) childNonEditable;
        JList listNonEditable = popupNonEditable.getList();
        listNonEditable.setBackground(Color.white);
        listNonEditable.setSelectionBackground(Color.red);

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 10));
        frame.add(editableComboBox);
        frame.add(nonEditableComboBox);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(100, 100);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ComboTest ct = new ComboTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: similar postings:
[link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569759/border-editor-when-rendering-item-in-jcombobox-and-editable-false)
[link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169022/jcombobox-does-not-behave-same-as-jtextfield-how-can-i-have-it-look-similar)
[link3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322903/how-do-you-change-border-of-the-pop-up-section-of-a-jcombobox)
[link4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776893/remove-border-from-jcombobox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- How about override MetalComboBoxUI#paintCurrentValueBackground(...)

  - using JDK 1.7.0_17, Windows 7

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.*;

public class ComboBoxUIDemo {
  private static Color BORDER = Color.GRAY;
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    //UIManager.put("ComboBox.foreground", Color.WHITE);
    //UIManager.put("ComboBox.background", Color.BLACK);
    //UIManager.put("ComboBox.selectionForeground", Color.CYAN);
    //UIManager.put("ComboBox.selectionBackground", Color.BLACK);

    //UIManager.put("ComboBox.buttonDarkShadow", Color.WHITE);
    //UIManager.put("ComboBox.buttonBackground", Color.GRAY);
    //UIManager.put("ComboBox.buttonHighlight", Color.WHITE);
    //UIManager.put("ComboBox.buttonShadow", Color.WHITE);
    //UIManager.put("ComboBox.editorBorder", BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));

    Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();

    UIManager.put("ComboBox.border", BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++) { // Defalut
      JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<>(makeModel());
      if(i%2==0) setEditable(cb);
      setPopupBorder(cb);
      box.add(cb);
      box.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    }

    {
      // Override MetalComboBoxUI#paintCurrentValueBackground(...)
      JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<>(makeModel());
      cb.setUI(new MetalComboBoxUI() {
        @Override public void paintCurrentValueBackground(
        Graphics g, Rectangle bounds, boolean hasFocus) {
          //if (MetalLookAndFeel.usingOcean()) {
          if(MetalLookAndFeel.getCurrentTheme() instanceof OceanTheme) {
            g.setColor(MetalLookAndFeel.getControlDarkShadow());
            g.drawRect(bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.width, bounds.height - 1);
            //COMMENTOUT>>>
            //g.setColor(MetalLookAndFeel.getControlShadow());
            //g.drawRect(bounds.x + 1, bounds.y + 1, bounds.width - 2,
            //           bounds.height - 3);
            //<<<COMMENTOUT
            if (hasFocus && !isPopupVisible(comboBox) && arrowButton != null) {
              g.setColor(listBox.getSelectionBackground());
              Insets buttonInsets = arrowButton.getInsets();
              if (buttonInsets.top > 2) {
                g.fillRect(bounds.x + 2, bounds.y + 2, bounds.width - 3,
                           buttonInsets.top - 2);
              }
              if (buttonInsets.bottom > 2) {
                g.fillRect(bounds.x + 2, bounds.y + bounds.height -
                           buttonInsets.bottom, bounds.width - 3,
                           buttonInsets.bottom - 2);
              }
            }
          } else if (g == null || bounds == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException(
              "Must supply a non-null Graphics and Rectangle");
          }
        }
      });
      setPopupBorder(cb);

      box.add(cb);
      box.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    }

    UIManager.put("ComboBox.border", BorderFactory.createLineBorder(BORDER));
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++) { // BasicComboBoxUI
      JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<>(makeModel());
      if(i%2==0) setEditable(cb);
      cb.setUI(new BasicComboBoxUI());
      setPopupBorder(cb);
      box.add(cb);
      box.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    }

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,20,10,20));
    p.add(box, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    return p;
  }
  private static void setEditable(JComboBox cb) {
    cb.setEditable(true);
    ComboBoxEditor editor = cb.getEditor();
    Component c = editor.getEditorComponent();
    if(c instanceof JTextField) {
      JTextField tf = (JTextField)c;
      tf.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1,1,1,0,BORDER));
    }
  }
  private static void setPopupBorder(JComboBox cb) {
    Object o = cb.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleChild(0);
    JComponent c = (JComponent)o;
    c.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0,1,1,1,BORDER));
  }
  private static DefaultComboBoxModel<String> makeModel() {
    DefaultComboBoxModel<String> m = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
    m.addElement("1234");
    m.addElement("5555555555555555555555");
    m.addElement("6789000000000");
    return m;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
//     OceanTheme theme = new OceanTheme() {
//       @Override protected ColorUIResource getSecondary2() {
//         return new ColorUIResource(Color.RED);
//       }
//     };
//     MetalLookAndFeel.setCurrentTheme(theme);

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new ComboBoxUIDemo().makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you aterai! that seems to solve my problem! i'm still busy applying it to my program.

Answer (score 2):

- not able to ...., every have got the same Borders, there must be another issue, 1st and 2nd. are editable JComboBoxes
- for better help sooner post an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable, just about two JComboBoxes, Native OS, compiled in JDK, runned in JRE

WinXP Java6

[image]

Win7 Java7

[image: > will be edited]

Win7 Java6

[image: > will be edited]

Win8 Java6

[image]

Win8 Java7

[image: > will be edited]

from code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxButton;

public class MyComboBox {

    private Vector<String> listSomeString = new Vector<String>();
    private JComboBox someComboBox = new JComboBox(listSomeString);
    private JComboBox editableComboBox = new JComboBox(listSomeString);
    private JComboBox non_EditableComboBox = new JComboBox(listSomeString);
    private JFrame frame;

    public MyComboBox() {
        listSomeString.add("-");
        listSomeString.add("Snowboarding");
        listSomeString.add("Rowing");
        listSomeString.add("Knitting");
        listSomeString.add("Speed reading");
//
        someComboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        someComboBox.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 16));
        someComboBox.setEditable(true);
        someComboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        ((JTextField) someComboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
//
        editableComboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        editableComboBox.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 16));
        editableComboBox.setEditable(true);
        JTextField text = ((JTextField) editableComboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent());
        text.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        JComboBox coloredArrowsCombo = editableComboBox;
        Component[] comp = coloredArrowsCombo.getComponents();
        for (int i = 0; i < comp.length; i++) {
            if (comp[i] instanceof MetalComboBoxButton) {
                MetalComboBoxButton coloredArrowsButton = (MetalComboBoxButton) comp[i];
                coloredArrowsButton.setBackground(null);
                break;
            }
        }
//
        non_EditableComboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        non_EditableComboBox.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 16));
//
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 10));
        frame.add(someComboBox);
        frame.add(editableComboBox);
        frame.add(non_EditableComboBox);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(100, 100);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UIManager.put("ComboBox.background", new ColorUIResource(Color.yellow));
        UIManager.put("JTextField.background", new ColorUIResource(Color.yellow));
        UIManager.put("ComboBox.selectionBackground", new ColorUIResource(Color.magenta));
        UIManager.put("ComboBox.selectionForeground", new ColorUIResource(Color.blue));
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyComboBox aCTF = new MyComboBox();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i've already seen your posting in another thread. i think that your comboboxes also show the inner border i am talking about!