# Is there a way to Change the JOptionPane layout, like the color at the top and the image at the top left?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am curious, I am wondering if there exist a way to make the top of the JOptionPane into a different color, say red or orange. Also i was wondering how to change the image on the left of the JOptionPane. I am guessing it is not possible because it is already a method being used from java. But i am no expert.

Comment: `make the top of the JOptionPane into a different color` are you meaning toolbar with close button

Comment: [part of Look and Feels can do that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3954646/714968) or for WindowsLookAndFeel is possible some dirty hacks too, not good way for newbee use proper Look and Feel instead

Answer (score 7):

There are three options here:

1. Use one of the predefined icons using the respective message type:
   `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Eggs are not supposed to be green.", "Inane error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);`
2. Use a custom icon:
   `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Eggs are not supposed to be green.", "Inane custom dialog", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icon);`
3. Use a look & feel to have consistent icons all over your application: [How to Set the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)

Have a look at [this page of the Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more information on dialogs.

Answer (score 6):

You can add your own ImageIcon to a JOptionPane -- check out the API, and try calling the methods with an Icon field, passing in your own ImageIcon to see how this works. You can also create a complex JPanel, a full fledged GUI-containing JPanel, and make it the basis for your JOptionPane, simply by passing it in as the Object parameter (usually the second paramter) of the `JOptionPane.showXXX(...)` method.

Another option is to create and use your own modal JDialog.

A working code :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JOptionPaneExample
{
    private void createAndDisplayGUI()
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, getOptionPanel(), "Modified JOptionPane : ", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {   
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new JOptionPaneExample().createAndDisplayGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private JPanel getOptionPanel()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        try
        {
            java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/gaganisonline/images/swing/geek.gif");
            ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(url);
            JLabel label = new JLabel("I am one MODIFIED JOPTIONPANE's LABEL.", image, JLabel.RIGHT);
            panel.add(label);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return panel;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like @rolve's answer better. 1+ to him.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : Sorry for the edit, though, this thing as I learned from YOU once, was amazing, so just added a small code part. I wish All can learn this thing, and see how easy and wonderful it can work :-) Revert it back, if I did anything wrong in any way :(