# How to navigate in JTabbedPane when we have multiple tabs open?

Tags: java, swing

In a jtabbedpane if i have multiple tabs opened and orientation is with respect en_GB locale(Left to Right) then it provides a navigating buttons.
But if i use arabic locale(Right to Left) then it wont provide the navigation buttons to navigate the tabs. Please need halp on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can to set/override [ComponentOrientation for JTabbedPane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10909273/714968) and/or with Locale too

Comment: I am able to set the orientation, but not able to navigate between the tabs if its from Right to Left.

Comment: not sure what and how, please edit your question with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), sure you can use my linked code, but I need to see your idea(s)

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6475412/230513) using `applyComponentOrientation()`.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad could you please to comment this one, meaning to comment  `not able to navigate between the tabs if its from Right to Left` ???

Comment: If there are many tabs opened which cannot fit in the tabbedpane then it provides a scroll buttons to switch between the tabs of the orientation is from Left to Right, which is not available if the orientation is from Right to Left.

Comment: this is another reason why overlay [expected possition of navigations buttons with own navigations bar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9734016/714968), with two JButtons and finally own Icons (not possible directly because navigations bar isn't accesible from implemented API)