# Change icon of JComboBox arrow button

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, look-and-feel, synth

Thanks for reply

but this what i want to do:

When a key is pressed in an editable combobox, I want the popup menu of the jcombobox to appear automatically, and get the text written in it, but when I changed the icon of the arrow button,the icon changed but the popup menu doesn't appear when key is pressed.

When I tried to do this in Windows look and feel, it worked fine without any problems, but in Synth look and feel, it didn't work. I searched for two days but I couldn't solve the problem.

I tried to use document listener but nothing changed or i didnt use it correctly

I hope my problem is clarified this time

```
JTextField editor;
.
.
.
editor = (JTextField) jComboBox1.getEditor().getEditorComponent();

\\ 

editor.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    if (jComboBox1.isDisplayable())
    {
        jComboBox1.setPopupVisible(true);
    }

         System.out.println(editor.getText());
}
});

\\ change arrowbutton icon

jComboBox1.setUI(new SynthComboBoxUI() {

   @Override
   protected JButton createArrowButton() {
      JButton btn = new JButton();
      btn.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Image/error3.png")));
      return btn;
   }
});
```

Comment: Is all of your Java code fully left justified? It must be hard to read.

Answer (score 4):

1. don't use [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html), use DocumentFilter for filtering unwanted chars or [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)
2. [JTextComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) returns Document (derived `JTextField` or `JFormattedTextField` from `JComboBox` / `JSpinner`)
3. put [Icon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) to the definitions saved into `xml file` for `Synt`, you can to test that by derive  SynthButtonUI from JComboBOx
4. from Synth L&F to use `Nimbus`
5. use [Custom Look and Feel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954616/look-and-feel-in-java/3954646#3954646), part of them override methods from `BasicXxxUI` directly